# HTTP POST works in application but not in service

Tags: android, web-services, http, post

### HTTP POST

My android application needs to do an HTTP post to a php script. The post needs to happen in a service. For some reason the POST gets a connection timeout when running in the service but if i copy the method to the onCreate event of my application and run, it works fine. I have no idea what could be different.
This is my method (timeout code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000))

```
    String url = "http://myurl/" +
  "?tmpl=javascript" +
  "&mode=recieved" + 
  "&id=" + id;
  URI uri = null;
  try {
   url = url.replace(" ", "%20");
   uri = new URI(url);
  } catch (URISyntaxException e1) {
   // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   e1.printStackTrace();
  }
  HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(uri);
  HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
  // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
  int timeoutConnection = 10000;
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
  // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
  // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
  int timeoutSocket = 10000;
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

  DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
  try {
   HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
  } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage());
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

The Android manifest declares the service like this

```
<service android:name=".Notifications.PushService" 
       android:label="Application Notifications Service">
     
    </service>
```

I do have uses internet in the permissions.
Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!