# How to set time out in android

Tags: android, timer

Is there any way to set time out in android, if there is no response from server for specific period.

Comment: Could you be more specific? Ofcourse there is, which class do you use for your request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is code that i used for time out

```
   uri = new URI(url);
            HttpGet method = new HttpGet(uri);
            method.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            int timeoutConnection = 60000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters,
                    timeoutConnection);
            int timeoutSocket = 65000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(method);
            HttpEntity responseEntity = response.getEntity();
            statuscode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

Put this in a try catch block and if exceeds the time it will throw the exception

Comment: pls check following link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java

Answer (score 0):

Try checking the coonectivity to the url first before seeking data reply

Comment: Yes i have done checking with getNetWorkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting()