# Android https timeout

Tags: android, service

I am getting huge data from a database and I have to display the data in a table form. Please provide me a way to get the data from the web service and display it in a table.

Comment: How huge is huge?  Terabytes, Gigabytes, Megabytes?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set time out in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4274365/how-to-set-time-out-in-android)

Answer (score 0):

You should get data from web and parse it then put all the data on map/list/arrays then create custom list according to your need then put this data structure in listview.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to actually use HTTP client or url connection with a buffer for reading to get the data (search on google for tutorials and examples). also be sure to set a larger timeout because you will be pulling a lot of data. then depending on the format of your data start parsing it, maybe store it in a database, Arraylist or something like that and then make a list with an adapter to show the data.

[Url connection](http://www.anddev.org/getting_data_from_the_web_urlconnection_via_http-t351-s15.html)

hope this helps.