# commons httpclient - Adding query string parameters to GET/POST request

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using commons HttpClient to make an http call to a Spring servlet. I need to add a few parameters in the query string. So I do the following:

```
HttpRequestBase request = new HttpGet(url);
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter("key1", "value1");
params.setParameter("key2", "value2");
params.setParameter("key3", "value3");
request.setParams(params);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
httpClient.execute(request);
```

However when i try to read the parameter in the servlet using

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getParameter("key");
```

it returns null. In fact the parameterMap is completely empty. When I manually append the parameters to the url before creating the HttpGet request, the parameters are available in the servlet. Same when I hit the servlet from the browser using the URL with queryString appended.

What's the error here? In httpclient 3.x, GetMethod had a setQueryString() method to append the querystring. What's the equivalent in 4.x?

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Here is how you would add query string parameters using HttpClient 4.2 and later:

```
URIBuilder builder = new URIBuilder("http://example.com/");
builder.setParameter("parts", "all").setParameter("action", "finish");

HttpPost post = new HttpPost(builder.build());
```

The resulting URI would look like:

```
http://example.com/?parts=all&action=finish
```

Answer (score 34):

If you want to add a query parameter after you have created the request, try casting the `HttpRequest` to a `HttpBaseRequest`. Then you can change the URI of the casted request:

```
HttpGet someHttpGet = new HttpGet("http://google.de");

URI uri = new URIBuilder(someHttpGet.getURI()).addParameter("q",
        "That was easy!").build();

((HttpRequestBase) someHttpGet).setURI(uri);
```

Answer (score 13):

The `HttpParams` interface isn't there for specifying query string parameters, it's for specifying runtime behaviour of the `HttpClient` object.

If you want to pass query string parameters, you need to assemble them on the URL yourself, e.g.

```
new HttpGet(url + "key1=" + value1 + ...);
```

Remember to encode the values first (using `URLEncoder`).

Comment: Is there no way to add a query string parameter AFTER the request object has already been created? If not, is there another standard way to pass parameters to the servlet for any request method(GET/PUT/POST)?

Answer (score 5):

I am using httpclient 4.4.

For solr query I used the following way and it worked.

```
NameValuePair nv2 = new BasicNameValuePair("fq","(active:true) AND (category:Fruit OR category1:Vegetable)");
nvPairList.add(nv2);
NameValuePair nv3 = new BasicNameValuePair("wt","json");
nvPairList.add(nv3);
NameValuePair nv4 = new BasicNameValuePair("start","0");
nvPairList.add(nv4);
NameValuePair nv5 = new BasicNameValuePair("rows","10");
nvPairList.add(nv5);

HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
URI uri = new URIBuilder(request.getURI()).addParameters(nvPairList).build();
            request.setURI(uri);

HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);    
if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() != 200) {

}

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                             new InputStreamReader((response.getEntity().getContent())));

String output;
System.out.println("Output  .... ");
String respStr = "";
while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
    respStr = respStr + output;
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

Comment: This answer would benefit from more explanation

Comment: This answer was very useful for my case because I couldn't find a way to initialise URIBuilder with a complete URI, example `http://myserver/apipath`. When initialised with it, URIBuilder only used `http://myserver` and ignored `/apipath`. The URI was provided externally so I didn't want to parse it manually just to use URIBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

This approach is ok but will not work for when you get params dynamically , sometimes 1, 2, 3 or more, just like a SOLR search query (for example)

Here is a more flexible solution. Crude but can be refined.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String host = "localhost";
    String port = "9093";

    String param = "/10-2014.01?description=cars&verbose=true&hl=true&hl.simple.pre=<b>&hl.simple.post=</b>";
    String[] wholeString = param.split("\\?");
    String theQueryString = wholeString.length > 1 ? wholeString[1] : "";

    String SolrUrl = "http://" + host + ":" + port + "/mypublish-services/carclassifications/" + "loc";

    GetMethod method = new GetMethod(SolrUrl );

    if (theQueryString.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
        method.setQueryString(new NameValuePair[]{
        });
    } else {
        String[] paramKeyValuesArray = theQueryString.split("&");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(paramKeyValuesArray);
        List<NameValuePair> nvPairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        for (String s : list) {
            String[] nvPair = s.split("=");
            String theKey = nvPair[0];
            String theValue = nvPair[1];
            NameValuePair nameValuePair = new NameValuePair(theKey, theValue);
            nvPairList.add(nameValuePair);
        }
        NameValuePair[] nvPairArray = new NameValuePair[nvPairList.size()];
        nvPairList.toArray(nvPairArray);
        method.setQueryString(nvPairArray);       // Encoding is taken care of here by setQueryString

    }
}
```

Comment: GetMethod ? is it from httpclient ? because the question is about it.

Comment: Yes, from org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.

Comment: ah yes, but it seems it's for the 3.x version, in 4.x, it's now org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet

Answer (score 0):

This is how I implemented my URL builder.
I have created one Service class to provide the params for the URL

```
public interface ParamsProvider {

    String queryProvider(List<BasicNameValuePair> params);

    String bodyProvider(List<BasicNameValuePair> params);
}
```

The Implementation of methods are below

```
@Component
public class ParamsProviderImp implements ParamsProvider {
    @Override
    public String queryProvider(List<BasicNameValuePair> params) {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        params.forEach(basicNameValuePair -> {
            if (first.get()) {
                query.append("?");
                query.append(basicNameValuePair.toString());
                first.set(false);
            } else {
                query.append("&");
                query.append(basicNameValuePair.toString());
            }
        });
        return query.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public String bodyProvider(List<BasicNameValuePair> params) {
        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
        AtomicBoolean first = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        params.forEach(basicNameValuePair -> {
            if (first.get()) {
                body.append(basicNameValuePair.toString());
                first.set(false);
            } else {
                body.append("&");
                body.append(basicNameValuePair.toString());
            }
        });
        return body.toString();
    }
}
```

When we need the query params for our URL, I simply call the service and build it.
Example for that is below.

```
Class Mock{
@Autowired
ParamsProvider paramsProvider;
 String url ="http://www.google.lk";
// For the query params price,type
 List<BasicNameValuePair> queryParameters = new ArrayList<>();
 queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", 100));
 queryParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("type", "L"));
url = url+paramsProvider.queryProvider(queryParameters);
// You can use it in similar way to send the body params using the bodyProvider

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using Java 8 and apache httpclient 4.5.13

```java
HashMap<String, String> customParams = new HashMap<>();
customParams.put("param1", "ABC");
customParams.put("param2", "123");

URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(baseURL);

for (String paramKey : customParams.keySet()) {
    uriBuilder.addParameter(paramKey, customParams.get(paramKey));
}

System.out.println(uriBuilder.build().toASCIIString()); // ENCODED URL
System.out.println(uriBuilder.build().toString); // NORMAL URL
```

Full example with DTO

```java
public class HttpResponseDTO {
    private Integer statusCode;
    private String body;
    private String errorMessage;
    
    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }
    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }
    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }
    public String getErrorMessage() {
        return errorMessage;
    }
    public void setErrorMessage(String errorMessage) {
        this.errorMessage = errorMessage;
    }
}
```

```java
    /**
     * 
     * @param destinationURL
     * @param params
     * @param headers
     * @return HttpResponseDTO
     */
    public static HttpResponseDTO get(String baseURL, Boolean encodeURL, HashMap<String, String> params, HashMap<String, String> headers) {

        final HttpResponseDTO httpResponseDTO = new HttpResponseDTO();      

        // ADD PARAMS IF
        if (params != null && Boolean.FALSE.equals(params.isEmpty())) {
            URIBuilder uriBuilder;
            try {
                uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(baseURL);

                for (String paramKey : params.keySet()) {
                    uriBuilder.addParameter(paramKey, params.get(paramKey));
                }

                // CODIFICAR URL ?
                if (Boolean.TRUE.equals(encodeURL)) {
                    baseURL = uriBuilder.build().toASCIIString();
                } else {
                    baseURL = uriBuilder.build().toString();
                }
            } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
                httpResponseDTO.setStatusCode(500);
                httpResponseDTO.setErrorMessage("ERROR AL CODIFICAR URL: " + e.getMessage());
                return httpResponseDTO;
            }
        }


        // HACER PETICION HTTP
        try (CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault()) {            
            final HttpGet get = new HttpGet(baseURL);   

            // ADD HEADERS
            if (headers != null && Boolean.FALSE.equals(headers.isEmpty())) {           
                for (String headerKey : headers.keySet()) {
                    get.setHeader(headerKey, headers.get(headerKey));
                }           
            }

            try (CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(get);) {
                HttpEntity httpEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (httpEntity != null) {
                    httpResponseDTO.setBody(EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity));
                    httpResponseDTO.setStatusCode(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                }
            } catch(Exception e) {
                httpResponseDTO.setStatusCode(500);
                httpResponseDTO.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
                return httpResponseDTO;
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            httpResponseDTO.setStatusCode(500);
            httpResponseDTO.setErrorMessage(e.getMessage());
            return httpResponseDTO;
        }

        return httpResponseDTO;
    }
```

Comment: This is basically the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14690178/6670491) but with some sample code for testing.