# Receive specific data from a webservice using REST API

Tags: java, json, swing

I want to get data from this API: http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries. I need that user can write name of the `Country` in `JTextField` and get `NativeName` and `CurrencyCode` in `JTextArea`.

I have such a code, it returns data only for Country which I write in HttpGet: `HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=Australia");`.

But how can I do that user can write the Country and get info for it which he wants?

Comment: Well, instead of always sending "Australia", send what the text field contains.

Comment: yes, but how can I do this?

Comment: By calling getText() on the text field. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use this

```
request = new HttpGet(
        "http://countryapi.gear.host/v1/Country/getCountries?pName=country"
                .replaceAll("country", yourTextField.getText())
);
```

Comment: Or use Apache `URIBuilder` to build... look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9907161/commons-httpclient-adding-query-string-parameters-to-get-post-request