# Java Get request with parameter and Authetification

Tags: java, api, get

I woudlike to put some parameter in my request (code value and name value) :

```
    String code = "001";
    String name = "AAA";       

    HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);
    String auth = user + ":" + mdp;

    byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
            auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));

    String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);

    request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);

    HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);

    int statusCode = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
```

How can I do this with authentification request ?

Something like : `code=001&name=AAA` in the URL

Comment: Add the parameters to `url`, e.g., `url += "?" + code=001&name=AAA"`.  This is somewhat ugly, so there are probably (hopefully) more elegant ways to build the string used in `HttpGet`.  Those parameters should also be properly encoded.

Comment: @AndrewS How can I do that more elegant ?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14690178/6650475) should help.

Comment: @AndrewS Thank you very much ! that's exactly what I'm looking for !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `URIBuilder` to construct your URL

```
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URIBuilder;
//...
final String URI_PARAM_CODE = "code";
final String URI_PARAM_NAME = "name";

String code = "001";
String name = "AAA";

URI uri = new URIBuilder("http://google.com")
    .setParameter(URI_PARAM_CODE, code)
    .setParameter(URI_PARAM_NAME, name)
    .build();
```

You can also set other useful attributes before calling `URIBuilder::build` - please refer to [Apache URIBuilder documentation](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient/4.2.4/org/apache/http/client/utils/URIBuilder.html).