# Android HttpClient HttpPost "browser name" and OS in request header

Tags: android

Our client wants to see some information in POST request headers we are sending, equivalent to what browsers send. Here's a server log for illustration:

```
[01/Sep/2013:23:11:57 +0100] "POST /script.php?par=test HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "-" "-"
```

And it should be like this:

```
[01/Sep/2013:23:11:57 +0100] "POST /script.php?par=test HTTP/1.1" 200 4 "appVer 1.0" "OS version 4.3"
```

I'm using HttpPost class and some script that wrapps SSL around HttpClient for HTTPS so I'd like to stay with current implementation.
To add this info I tried

```
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri.toASCIIString()); 
post.setHeader("appVersion", appVer);
```

and

```
HttpParams httpParams = new BasicHttpParams();
httpParams.setParameter("appVersion", appVer);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParams);
```

without success. How do I do this?

Comment: Try the solution from [this][1] one.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424425/cant-get-httpparams-working-with-postrequest

Comment: That's not it, this is: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14524307/552735
user-agent is the keyword :)