# android is hang while android don't find connection

Tags: android

I am creating an android application but while(if?) server is not found, it will hang the tool kit (SDK/emulator?). 
I have attached my login code. Please help me to find the solution. I just want that if server is not available, my application will stay on at the login page without hanging itself.

when I debugged my code I didn't get value of httpResponse and after this line

```
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
```

the problem occurred

```
public String login(String userName, String password){
        try {
            String url = URL+ "?flag="+"on"+"&user="+userName+"&pass="+password;
            httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpclient.execute(httpPost);
            int statuscode = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            if (statuscode == 200) {
                String responseMsg = getResponse(httpResponse); 
                return responseMsg;
            }else{
                Log.e(TAG, statuscode+"");
            }
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage(),e);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also should consider to define a timeout (e.g. 5 seconds) so that the system does not try to connect to an unreachable server for a long time.

```
final HttpParams httpParams = httpClient.getParams();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
```

Comment: where should i write this code.. in login method's try block??

Comment: You can write it just after `httpClient` initialization. There is no need to set it on each request. Consider of making it configurable (via properties/preferences).

Answer (score 2):

Check out this [How to set HttpResponse timeout for Android in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java/1565243#1565243). And you *really* should do all your network communications in a separate thread/AsyncTask and not on your main thread.

Answer (score 2):

If your UI on your emulator hangs you probably do network stuff on the UI thread - which will block all UI operations until the network operation is done. Read how to run this code in a thread here:
http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html

Answer (score 1):

Did you get an exception of some sort? If the URL isn't formatted properly you will get `MalformedURLException` and if the server isn't available/link is broken `IOException`.

You want to pass the response through a `ResponseHandler`

```
ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
try {
   responseString = mHttpClient.execute(post, responseHandler);
   Log.d(TAG, "doHTTPpost responseString = " + responseString);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
   //handle it 
} catch (IOException e) {
  //handle it
} catch (IllegalStateException e) {
  //handle it              
} finally {
  //handle it
}
```