# android - How to set Timeout

Tags: android

In My application i am calling the web service method but it takes more time for the response.

Because of without time specifying,  i got the following Exception. How to handle it.
 java.net.socketException: connection Reset.

So i want to implement the timeout for that particular web service method. It means suppose web service response not get after the specified time then it will generate timeout exception. how to implement it.

can anybody help me?

thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set HttpResponse timeout for Android in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java). Gee, that sidebar sure is useful.

Comment: where i have to put this code? In web service method or any other

Answer (score 0):

```
URL URLObj = null;
HttpURLConnection ConnObj = null;
URLObj = new URL("Http://Url.to.the/webservice");
ConnObj = (HttpURLConnection) URLObj .openConnection();
ConnObj .setConnectTimeout(5000); // This will set the desired time out for the connection request
```

Comment: This placed the after calling the web service method. Instead of "Http://Url.to.the/webservice" i am putting the my web service url.is it correct?