# Android HttpGet request with a very long URL

Tags: android

I am currently faced to a strange problem.
I have to contact a web service, with a very long URL (there is some XML inside). The length of one of them is **943** characters.
Most of the time, the request failed with a NoHttpResponseException.
I newly added a RetryHandler, which do his job, and the request finally worked, but the execute time was **246** seconds!
I reduced the timeout, to something like 30 seconds, and occasionally, the request work.
Is there something to know about long URL to make it work better?
Or, is it just prohibited on Android?
I precise that all connection with another tinier URL (even like **200** chars) perfectly work.

Here the source code of the Http connection (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)):

```
DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(hc.getParams(), false);
        HttpParams httpParameters = hc.getParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        int timeoutConnection = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 10000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        hc.setParams(httpParameters);
        
        HttpRequestRetryHandler retryHandler = new HttpRequestRetryHandler() {

            public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount,
                    HttpContext context) {
                // retry a max of x times
                if(executionCount >= 5){
                    return false;
                }
                if(exception instanceof NoHttpResponseException){
                    return true;
                } else if (exception instanceof ClientProtocolException){
                    return true;
                } 
                return false;
            }
        };
        hc.setHttpRequestRetryHandler(retryHandler);
        
        url = Tool.prepareURL(url);
        Log.d(LogFilter.EXECUTE, url);
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);
        if (eTag != null) {
            get.addHeader(HEADER_IF_NONE_MATCH, eTag);
        }
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse rp = hc.execute(get);
        Log.d(LogFilter.EXECUTE, "temps execute: "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-time));
        return rp;
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: why not just add POST key => values instead of GET?

Comment: The server side is fixed, so I think I can't?

Comment: so you don't have control of the server? explore their services and see if you can POST

Comment: I tried POST, but the server rejected the request. However, the request fail in like 1,5second.