# Cancel HTTP Post File Upload To Server During Write - Android

Tags: php, android, file-upload, dialog, http-post

I've been going crazy trying to figure this out. I've looked into possible solutions on SO, including [using finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4778754/kill-activity-on-back-button), [killing the process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16851638/android-kill-process), [killing the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105673/android-how-to-kill-an-application-with-all-its-activities), the following 5 ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8284027/closing-an-httpurlconnection-before-the-response-is-complete), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12383854/how-to-stop-httpurlconnection-connect-on-android), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391250/cancel-an-ongoing-connection-when-user-presses-back), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7140565/how-do-i-cancel-an-android-http-request), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650246/how-to-cancel-an-dialog-themed-like-activity-when-touched-outside-the-window)) and many more, but none of them seem to quite do the trick.

**What I'm currently able to do:**

I currently have functionality to open a custom File Dialog activity from my main app. From this dialog, I select which specific file to upload to the server. The server is simply an Apache server on my local machine, which is connected to the same Wi-Fi network as the Samsung S4 that I'm running the app on. I am able to select the file to upload, which starts a new activity and shows a progress dialog. Assuming the server, Wi-Fi, and phone are all properly connected to each other, the file uploads as expected. This file uploading process uses an HTTP Post request.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I want to be able to cancel the file upload at any point, but specifically in the middle of writing the file to the server. This is motivated by three main scenarios: 1) If the file is huge, is taking forever to upload, and the user wants to stop the upload, return to the File Dialog, and choose a different file to upload, 2) If the user chose the wrong file and wants to return to the File Dialog to chose the correct one, and 3) If the server is not properly connected, the HTTP post is hanging, and the user wants to stop the file uploading and then return later once everything is properly connected.

**What I've tried so far:**

The first thing I tried was to simply make the progress dialog cancelable, as follows:

```
DialogInterface.OnCancelListener onCancelListener = new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

@Override
public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
    finish();
    }
};

dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "", "Uploading file...", true, true, onCancelListener);
```

This, however, still allowed the upload to finish.

The second thing I tried was to simply interrupt the file uploading thread (using Thread.interrupt), but the file uploading still finished.

The third thing I tried was to disconnect the HttpURLConnection. I tried this with and without synchronizing the relevant blocks of code, but the file uploading still completed. An exception would be thrown, saying the socket was closed, but it wasn't thrown until it attempted to get the server response code, instead of immediately when it started writing as I had expected.

The fourth (and main) thing I tried was to close the DataOutputStream when the back button is pressed. I tried this with and without synchronizing the relevant blocks of code, but the file uploading still completed. However, if I close the DataOutputStream before I start writing to the buffer on the server, the stream closes, I get an IOException, and the file uploading is successfully cancelled. I cannot seem to figure out how to cancel the file uploading after the data has started to write to the server.

In other posts on SO, people suggest using finish(), System.exit(0), android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid()), HttpClient, AsyncTask, and plenty of other things, but none of them really seem to be what I'm looking for, except for maybe AsyncTask, though I'm still not convinced that's what I'm looking for.

Is what I'm trying to do even possible? I have a feeling it may not be...

I hope my question is clear enough and specific enough. If not, please let me know what I can clarify, what I left out, and what makes absolutely no sense! =P

**FileDialog Code:**

```
package com.example.<package_name>;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.<package_name>.ListenerList.FireHandler;
import com.example.<package_name>.utils.UploadToServer;

public class FileDialog extends Activity {
    public static boolean cancelled;
    private static final String PARENT_DIR = "..";
    private final String TAG = getClass().getName();
    private String[] fileList;
    private File currentPath;

    public interface FileSelectedListener {
        void fileSelected(File file);
    }

    public interface DirectorySelectedListener {
        void directorySelected(File directory);
    }

    private ListenerList<FileSelectedListener> fileListenerList = new ListenerList<FileDialog.FileSelectedListener>();
    private ListenerList<DirectorySelectedListener> dirListenerList = new ListenerList<FileDialog.DirectorySelectedListener>();
    private final Activity activity;
    private boolean selectDirectoryOption;
    private String fileEndsWith;

    /**
     * @param activity
     * @param initialPath
     */
    public FileDialog(Activity activity, File path) {
        this.activity = activity;
        if (!path.exists())
            path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        loadFileList(path);
    }

    /**
     * @return file dialog
     */
    public Dialog createFileDialog() {
        Dialog dialog = null;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);

        builder.setTitle("Select a file to upload. Current path = "
                + currentPath.getPath());
        if (selectDirectoryOption) {
            builder.setPositiveButton("Select directory",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Log.d(TAG, currentPath.getPath());
                            fireDirectorySelectedEvent(currentPath);
                        }
                    });
        }

        builder.setItems(fileList, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String fileChosen = fileList[which];
                File chosenFile = getChosenFile(fileChosen);
                cancelled = true;
                if (chosenFile.isDirectory()) {
                    loadFileList(chosenFile);
                    dialog.cancel();
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    showDialog();
                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, UploadToServer.class);
                    Bundle fileInfo = new Bundle();
                    fileInfo.putString(
                            UploadToServer.UPLOAD_FILE_DIRECTORY_KEY,
                            currentPath.getPath());
                    fileInfo.putString(UploadToServer.UPLOAD_FILE_NAME_KEY,
                            chosenFile.getName());
                    intent.putExtras(fileInfo); // Pass the file info to the
                                                // UploadToServer activity
                    activity.startActivity(intent);
                    fireFileSelectedEvent(chosenFile);
                }
            }
        });

        dialog = builder.show();
        return dialog;
    }

    public void addFileListener(FileSelectedListener listener) {
        fileListenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeFileListener(FileSelectedListener listener) {
        fileListenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    public void setSelectDirectoryOption(boolean selectDirectoryOption) {
        this.selectDirectoryOption = selectDirectoryOption;
    }

    public void addDirectoryListener(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
        dirListenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeDirectoryListener(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
        dirListenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    /**
     * Show file dialog
     */
    public void showDialog() {
        createFileDialog().show();
    }

    private void fireFileSelectedEvent(final File file) {
        fileListenerList
                .fireEvent(new FireHandler<FileDialog.FileSelectedListener>() {
                    @Override
                    public void fireEvent(FileSelectedListener listener) {
                        listener.fileSelected(file);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void fireDirectorySelectedEvent(final File directory) {
        dirListenerList
                .fireEvent(new FireHandler<FileDialog.DirectorySelectedListener>() {
                    @Override
                    public void fireEvent(DirectorySelectedListener listener) {
                        listener.directorySelected(directory);
                    }
                });
    }

    private void loadFileList(File path) {
        this.currentPath = path;
        List<String> r = new ArrayList<String>();
        if (path.exists()) {
            if (path.getParentFile() != null)
                r.add(PARENT_DIR);
            FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
                @Override
                public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                    File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                    if (!sel.canRead())
                        return false;
                    if (selectDirectoryOption)
                        return sel.isDirectory();
                    else {
                        boolean endsWith = fileEndsWith != null ? filename
                                .toLowerCase().endsWith(fileEndsWith) : true;
                        return endsWith || sel.isDirectory();
                    }
                }
            };
            String[] fileList1 = path.list(filter);
            for (String file : fileList1) {
                r.add(file);
            }
        }
        fileList = (String[]) r.toArray(new String[] {});
    }

    private File getChosenFile(String fileChosen) {
        if (fileChosen.equals(PARENT_DIR))
            return currentPath.getParentFile();
        else
            return new File(currentPath, fileChosen);
    }

    public void setFileEndsWith(String fileEndsWith) {
        this.fileEndsWith = fileEndsWith != null ? fileEndsWith.toLowerCase()
                : fileEndsWith;
    }
}

class ListenerList<L> {
    private List<L> listenerList = new ArrayList<L>();

    public interface FireHandler<L> {
        void fireEvent(L listener);
    }

    public void add(L listener) {
        listenerList.add(listener);
    }

    public void fireEvent(FireHandler<L> fireHandler) {
        List<L> copy = new ArrayList<L>(listenerList);
        for (L l : copy) {
            fireHandler.fireEvent(l);
        }
    }

    public void remove(L listener) {
        listenerList.remove(listener);
    }

    public List<L> getListenerList() {
        return listenerList;
    }
}
```

**UploadToServer code:**

```
package com.example.<package_name>.utils;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.<package_name>.FileDialog;
import com.example.<package_name>.R;

public class UploadToServer extends Activity {

    /**
     * The key for the upload file path value passed through the start-up
     * intent.
     */
    public static final String UPLOAD_FILE_DIRECTORY_KEY = "UploadToServer.uploadFileDirectory";
    /**
     * The key for the upload file name value passed through the start-up
     * intent.
     */
    public static final String UPLOAD_FILE_NAME_KEY = "UploadToServer.uploadFileName";

    TextView messageText;
    Button uploadButton;
    int serverResponseCode = 0;
    ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    String upLoadServerUri = null;

    private String uploadFileDirectory;
    private String uploadFileName;

    private FileUploadRunnable fileUploadRunnable;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload_to_server);

        Bundle fileInfo = getIntent().getExtras();
        uploadFileDirectory = fileInfo.getString(UPLOAD_FILE_DIRECTORY_KEY);
        uploadFileName = fileInfo.getString(UPLOAD_FILE_NAME_KEY);

        messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);

        messageText.setText("Uploading file path :- " + uploadFileDirectory
                + "/" + uploadFileName);

        /************* Php script path ****************/
        upLoadServerUri = "http://<server_ip>/UploadToServer.php";

        DialogInterface.OnCancelListener onCancelListener = new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                finish();
            }
        };

        dialog = ProgressDialog.show(UploadToServer.this, "",
                "Uploading file...", true, true, onCancelListener);

        messageText.setText("uploading started.....");

        fileUploadRunnable = new FileUploadRunnable(uploadFileDirectory,
                uploadFileName);

        new Thread(fileUploadRunnable).start();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (fileUploadRunnable != null) {
            fileUploadRunnable.cancelUpload();
        }
        super.onBackPressed();
    }

    private class FileUploadRunnable implements Runnable {

        private final String uploadFileDirectory;
        private final String uploadFileName;
        private HttpURLConnection conn;
        private final Object dosLock;
        private boolean doUpload;
        DataOutputStream dos;

        public FileUploadRunnable(String uploadFileDirectory,
                String uploadFileName) {
            this.uploadFileDirectory = uploadFileDirectory;
            this.uploadFileName = uploadFileName;
            conn = null;
            Lock = new Object();
            doUpload = true;
            dos = null;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            uploadFile(uploadFileDirectory + "/" + uploadFileName);
        }

        /**
         * cancel the current upload
         */
        public void cancelUpload() {
            synchronized (dosLock) {
                if (dos != null) {
                    try {
                        dos.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                doUpload = false;
            }
        }

        private void uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

            String fileName = sourceFileUri;
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";
            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

            if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

                dialog.dismiss();

                Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                        + uploadFileDirectory + uploadFileName);

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                                + uploadFileDirectory + uploadFileName);
                    }
                });

                return;

            } else {
                try {
                    // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                    URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                    // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                    conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                    conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                    conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                    conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName);

                    synchronized (dosLock) {

                        if (!doUpload) {
                            return;
                        }

                        dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                        dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                        dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                        dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                    } // end synchronization block

                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                            sourceFile);

                    // create a buffer of maximum size
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                    // read file and write it into form...
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                    while (bytesRead > 0) {

                        synchronized (dosLock) {
                            dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                            bufferSize = Math
                                    .min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0,
                                    bufferSize);
                        }
                    }

                    // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                    dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                    // Responses from the server (code and message)
                    serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                    String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                    Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                            + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                    if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {

                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                        + " http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                        + uploadFileName;

                                messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                                        "File Upload Complete.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    // close the streams //
                    fileInputStream.close();
                    dos.flush();
                    dos.close();

                } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    ex.printStackTrace();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText
                                    .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                                    "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });

                    Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(),
                            ex);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO if doUpload is false here, then this is expected, so pop-up a toast.
                    // TODO if doUpload is true here, then this is NOT expected, so open an error dialog.

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO this is for unexpected exceptions, so open an error dialog.

                    dialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                            Toast.makeText(UploadToServer.this,
                                    "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                            "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
                }
                dialog.dismiss();

            } // End else block
        }
    }
}
```

**Server code:**

UploadToServer.php

```
<?php

    $file_directory = 'uploads/';
    $file_name = 'configuration.xml';
    $file_path = $file_directory . $file_name;
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
        echo "success";
    } else{
        echo "fail";
    }
 ?>
```

My code is adapted from [this codebase](http://androidexample.com/Upload_File_To_Server_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=83&aaid=106).

Comment: So, have you tried `org.apache.http.client` with `httpPost.abort()`?

Comment: @AlexanderZhak: I have not, but would it really have any different functionality than HttpURLConnection? It just seems like Thread.interrupt, HttpURLConnection.disconnet, HttpPost.abort, AsyncTask.cancel, HttpClient.close, HttpClient.close, and Httpclient.getConnectionManager.shutdown all do basically the same thing, but under different names. Is this not the case?