# JSON response cutting off part way through

Tags: java, android, json

When downloading a JSON array, it cuts off 1/4 of the way through the string, its pretty huge - but it should get the entire string.

There are no errors thrown in the LogCat. This is the method I am using, I have been through it a few times and cant see a reason why it is cutting off. I am pretty new to this however.

```
public static JSONArray getJSONfromURL(String url){

    //initialize
    InputStream is = null;   
    String result = "";   
    JSONArray jArray = null;

    //http post
    try {

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);    
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        is = entity.getContent();    

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());   
    }
    //convert response to string

    try {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);  
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();   
        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {   
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    } catch (Exception e) {    
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
    //try parse the string to a JSON object

    try {
        Log.d("log_tag", "jresult: " + result + "finish");
        jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        //Log.e("log_tag", "result: " + jArray.toString());

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
    }

    return jArray;
}
```

I think once this is cracked I will be set. I will make this a class to use in future projects too so I dont have to keep rebuilding it!

EDIT: For loop where markers should be added to map:

```
try{
        for(int i=0;i<arrayResultFromURL.length();i++){
            JSONObject json_data = arrayResultFromURL.getJSONObject(i);

            // assign attributes from the JSON string to local variables
            String id =json_data.getString("id");
            String title =json_data.getString("title");
            String strap =json_data.getString("strap");
            Double lat = (double) json_data.getDouble("lat");
            Double lon = (double) json_data.getDouble("long");

            theMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(new LatLng(lat, lon))
            .title(title)
            .snippet(strap));
        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "error in array: " + e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: what does result return and what is the expected result?

Comment: It should return all of this http://pastebin.com/KLr2Czsb and it cuts it 1/4 of the way through http://pastebin.com/bgSqbNxi

Comment: i can't see what's wrong with the code. try logging result and check

Comment: logcat isn't going to output absolutely everything.  I have huge JSON strings also that get cut off, usually right around 1000 characters.

Comment: @romo that could be a possibility, not all of the markers are showing on a map (will update my question with the for loop adding them, but everything is fine with them, as they display on the iOS app)

Comment: That's a single line, there aren't any newlines in your json. Maybe it's related to the size of the BufferedReader buffer? Can you try `JSONArray array = new JSONArray(HttpEntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()))`?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your problem comes from the way your are treating the response object. Check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192640/665823).

If not try to check the size of the response first to see if you are receving all.

```
httpResponse.getEntity().getContentLength()
```

Also just in case you didn't know there is a nice library (i've been using it since i found it) that simplifies json parsing ckeck it out [here](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).

Answer (score 0):

These type of things can best be done by libraries such as GSON or Jackson

Also, if your goal is to create a [JSONArray](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONArray.html), there is a constructor that takes in a [JSONTokener](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONTokener.html). JSONTokener can in turn be constructed from your InputStream.