# How to display a progressbar while connecting with server in android?

Tags: android, progress-bar

Here is my method to connect to server and get the response in MyUtilitiesActivity (timeout code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)).

```
 private static response = "";
public static String send(final Activity act, final String url, final String keys[], final String values[]) 
{ 
    try{
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.

        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.

        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);  

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        if(keys == null && values == null)
        {

            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(url);   
            // Execute HTTP Get Request 
            response = httpclient.execute(get, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();  
             
        }
        else if(keys != null && values != null && keys.length == values.length)
        {
            // Add your data   
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
            {
                nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair(keys[i], values[i])); 
            }

            HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            response = httpclient.execute(post, new BasicResponseHandler()).trim();  

        } 

    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        response = e + "";
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return response ;  

}
```

And i'am calling the above method on click of a button in MyTestActivity.

```
public onClick(View v)
{
String response =  MyUtilitiesActivity.send(MyTestActivity.this,    "http://www.google.com", null, null);

 //the code to be execute after getting the response from server
 }
```

Where do i display the progress bar? Inside onclick of a button or inside send() method? How to display it ? Please help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [**AsyncTask**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) concept which is known as [Painless Threading](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) in Android.

1. Put your send() method in Async's `doInBackGround()`
2. Start progress dialog at onPreExecute
3. and dismisss on `onPostExecute()`.

Comment: Put your send() method in Async's doInBackGround() : I'an unable to do this. Shall i call send method in doInBG() or shall i put the code in doInBG(). Could you please explain in detail . Thank you.

Comment: Yes you can put your send method's code in doInBack() also No Problem..!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the progress bar like this:

```
ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", 
                                    getString(R.string.Loading), true);
```

and when your long operation is gone, you should call `dialog.dismiss();`