# Android: setting connection time out for HttpPost

Tags: android, connection, httpclient

Actually this is what i must do to set the Connection Timeout (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)):

```
HttpGet httpPost = new HttpGet("www.xxxx.com/method");
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
// The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

but in my application i make the `httpClient` as a `Static field` in the MainActivities and use it in all the other Activities. Just to have session.

so, should i have this code in all the Activities:

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
// The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
```

and then

```
MainActivity.httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);
```

I just want to know, how i can set the `params` in the `MainActivity` and just use the httpClient in all the other Activitites rather than setting the params in every Activity.

Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

create variables like:

```
    private static final long CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT = 10000;
    private static final int CONN_TIMEOUT = 50000;
    private static final int SO_TIMEOUT = 50000;
```

and use this code with httppost:

```
    ConnManagerParams.setTimeout(params, CONN_MGR_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(params, CONN_TIMEOUT);
    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, SO_TIMEOUT);
```

Comment: i can't use methods like setTimeout() during declaring the Fields. SO i have to use these methods in the Activity. Which mean in every Activity.

Comment: i think ur requirement is httppost to the server without getting timeout excepetion .is it ??

Comment: No. I have to set ConnectionTimeout params to the httpClient, only once. And use the same httpClient(prams already set in MainActivity) in all other Activities. Till now i was not setting any params, so i made a static field of this httpClient in the MainActivity and used it as MainActivity.httpClient in all other Activities

Comment: what's ur requirement finally in brief??

Comment: create a httpClient in the MainActivity as a field like. public static DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); and setParameters in the MainActivity itself. And use it as MainActivity.httpclient in all other Activities

Comment: That is the requirement. The problem is i must setParams to this httpclient in onCreate() of the MainActivity. So, this won't reflect on any other Activity using MainActivity.httpclient

Comment: If i am using MainActivity.httpclient in other Activities i only get the httpclient without params set. So i have to set params in every Activity, after getting the client using MainActivity.httpclient. I want to know if there is a way to avoid setting params in every activity which uses this httpclient. I want to set the params only once.

Comment: k... first u create httpclient class in that u create params what u required.. and those will be useful for main activity and also for other activities like setters and getters

Comment: Fine, i will try that. But i have 1 more question. If i set the ConnectionTime to some 5 secs. and in 5 secs the connection is not established what will be the out come? i mean is there any message. How can i track if i got a ConnectionTimeOut?>? Thank You

Answer (score 3):

use a static code block in your main activity class to set the parameter.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static final DefaultHttpClient httpClient;

    static {    
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 3000);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, 5000);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
    }


   ...

}
```