# Android: how to get the ConnectionTimeOut Value set to a HttpClient

Tags: android, httpclient

I set the HttpParameters to a HttpClient.

Now i want to test whether they are set correctly. Actually i was doing it this way (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)):

```
public class MyHttpClient extends DefaultHttpClient {

    public MyHttpClient(int tc, int ts) {

        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        int timeoutConnection = tc;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = ts;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        ClientConnectionManager mgr = this.getConnectionManager();
        this.setParams(httpParameters);
    }
}
```

and creating an instance of it like this:

```
public static MyHttpClient httpclient = new MyHttpClient(5000, 5000);
```

How to know if this actually worked.

I tried this :

httpclient.getParams().toString();

and i got this as an output:

```
org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams@40520f20
```

seems like its the `Default Params` but not the one i set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use these line of code

```
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
    int timeoutConnection = 120000;
            HttpConnectionParams.getConnectionTimeout(httpParameters));
```

Comment: I have already set the params. I just want to get the values i set. Something like "httpclient.getParams().getConnectionTimeout".

Answer (score 1):

I Used:

```
HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
params.setParameter(HttpProtocolParams.USE_EXPECT_CONTINUE, false);
HttpProtocolParams.setVersion(params, HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1);
params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
params.setLongParameter(ConnManagerPNames.TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
```

Comment: I have already set the params. I just want to get the values i set. Something like "httpclient.getParams().getConnectionTimeout".

Comment: try httpClient.getParams().getIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);