# Send php query to server from android app response time

Tags: java, php, android, eclipse, http

I am trying to put an entry in database. This is the code I am using

```
String url = String.format("http://xxxxxxx/xxx/index.php?home=yes&pid=%s", pid);

        // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
        String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

        Log.e("abc", response);
        return response;
        } catch (ClientProtocolException es) 
        {   
            Log.e("x" , es.getMessage());
            return "";
        } catch (IOException e) 
        {
            Log.e("aasx" , e.getMessage());
            return "";
        }
```

This code works fine. Now when there is an internet connection problem, the code stuck at 
`httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);` for more than 2 minutes.

Is there any way in which it check for only few seconds and if no resposne then `catch the exceptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is similar to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java).

You just need to set a timeout for the HttpClient as shown in the answers there. This can be done by passing in an HttpParams object to the HttpClient constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too familiar with Java, but in doing something similar in Actionscript 3, there is a timeout number you can usually put on an HTTP request to stop trying after a certain amount of  time. I usually set this to 15-30 seconds for requests that should return quickly.