# Posting a url containing an underscore (_)

Tags: android

I am posting a url with params containg an underscore (_).

sample: `http://sdsdsds_asasasahjhd.com/dsdsdsd/login.json?`

I am posting it like this:

```
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://sdsdsds_asasasahjhd.com/dsdsdsd/login.json?");
    try {
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key1", "value1"));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("key2", "value2"));
        nameValuePairs
                .add(new BasicNameValuePair("key3", "value3"));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

When I am inspecting `httpclient.execute(httppost)` I am getting `IllegalArgumentException` and in catch in exception details it is telling `Host name cannot be null`.
Please specify any solution.

I have gone through some other questions here:

- [java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13007329/java-lang-illegalstateexception-target-host-must-not-be-null-or-set-in-paramet)
- [Host name may not be null in HttpResponse execute for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12537522/host-name-may-not-be-null-in-httpresponse-execute-for-android)

but no use as I am not encoding the whole url.

Comment: hostname can not contains underscore ...

Comment: It helps if you provide a (partial) stack trace and details about the line number where the exception occurs.

Comment: @Selvin but the same url is working in Iphone.

Comment: check RFC 952 and RFC 1123 ...

Comment: or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hostname#Restrictions_on_valid_host_names - is that a local (Windows?) server? WP says "Windows [does not] enforce the rule against using an underscore in hostnames"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it clearly states that the host name can not be null.. your url doesn't specify one..

a url is expected to be in the format

```
http://hostName.com/example..../example.json
```

Comment: This same url is working in Iphone then I think so it should work in android.

Comment: This is wrong. Actually, URI class does't support host name with underscore, but i'm in the process of searching the workaround(-1)

Answer (score 1):

I have an open-source library with network implementation mechanism. It has just receiver an workaround implementation. All you need it to set the host by reflection in case of troubles:

```
        final URI uriObj = new URI("https", host, path, null, null);
        if (uriObj.getHost() == null) {
            final Field hostField = URI.class.getDeclaredField("host");
            hostField.setAccessible(true);
            hostField.set(uriObj, host);
        }
        return uriObj;
```

The commit is [here](https://bitbucket.org/dzigoro/lid-commons/commits/22275d33e3d26b12f0a1d0563f058632d4baa938).

Answer (score 0):

`HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(String);`

This contructor will attempt to form a [URL](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) instance from the provided String. If this fails, you'll be dealing with a `null` value.

Please post the actual URL you're using and not a sample if you want us to be able to help you further.

Comment: sorry unable to post the actual url.Do you think it is all because of "_"?

Comment: no the underscore is not the issue its the format of your URL it does not look like a URL it has to have a tld in it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

See this link. Apache doesnt support underscore. You should change the url

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-911