# Android - Disscard connection before timeout

Tags: android, connection, timeout

First off all sorry for my english.. so I do not know if I know what I want to express correctly.. hope so:

If I run in a AsyncTask doInBackground in the following:

```
URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
conexion.setConnectTimeout (time_out);
conexion.connect ();
```

but before I cancel a asyntask Connection TIMEOUT exception continues until the timeout is there by way of indicating to cancel the task to stop trying to connect?

Regards

Edit: Code from the asyntask
http://pastebin.com/G60jKJ0n

Comment: you are saying that your connection time out happen before cancel it right ?

Comment: for example.. time_out=120000 miliseconds and i cancel at 20 seconds, the asyntask is canceled ok.. but.. conexion still try to connect

Comment: some tines this ill help http://stackoverflow.com/a/15631434

Comment: http://omtlab.com/http-connection-timeout-in-android/]

Comment: but my problem, not is the time to take the connection, my problem is that when i cancel the asyntask, i want that "conexion" stop still trying to connect (off course only the user cancel the asyntask if he think that it take too much time), but conexion still at time_out

Comment: Add at my message, the code in a pastebin link. If the connection take too much, and the user cancel.. go to onCancelled, but connection still trying connect in doInBackground until it gives an exception. 
So there is any way, to dismiss the connection when go to onCancelled?. 
One more question.. why the exception is SocketTimeoutException and not ConnectTimeoutException?

Thanks