# How To Get values from Android in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to implement server side for android. Forthis in android i use this code:

```
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        // Get the deviceID
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id", val[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("App_Name",val[2]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("App_Version", val[3]));
```

Now on server side i want to access these values and store it in database. My php code:

```
include('connectdb.php');

$Reg_ID=$_REQUEST['reg_id'];
$App_Name=$_REQUEST['App_Name'];
$App_Version=$_REQUEST['App_Version'];
    
if($_REQUEST['reg_id']!='NULL' && $_REQUEST['App_Name']!='NULL' && $_REQUEST['App_Version']!='NULL')
{   
    mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO  registration (Reg_ID, APP_Name,App_Version)
    VALUES ('".$_REQUEST['reg_id']."', '".$_REQUEST['App_Name']."','".$_REQUEST['App_Version']."')");

}   
else
{
}   

mysqli_close($con);
```

but in php i am getting these errors:

> Notice: Undefined index: reg_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\GCM\addReg.php on
> line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: App_Name in C:\xampp\htdocs\GCM\addReg.php on
> line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: App_Version in C:\xampp\htdocs\GCM\addReg.php
> on line 7
>
> Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, resource
> given in C:\xampp\htdocs\GCM\addReg.php on line 24

any help

**EDIT**

```
public class SendMail extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    private String endResult;
    HttpResponse response;


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... val) {

        String url=val[0];

        //Log.i("Url", url + "");

        //  Log.d("C2DM", "Sending registration ID to my application server");

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(url);



        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
    
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("reg_id", val[1]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("App_Name",val[2]));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("App_Version", val[3]));








        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        int timeoutConnection = 30000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 30000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient hc = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
        ResponseHandler<String> res = new BasicResponseHandler();





        try {
            post.addHeader("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            response = hc.execute(post);
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Log.i("endResult", "" + endResult);
        super.onPostExecute(result);


        publishProgress(endResult);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) {

        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        String result = values[0];



    }

}
```

(timeout code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000))

Comment: I am not android developer but try to create json array and then pass it to php. IN php decode that array and use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
include('connectdb.php');

//First, check whether the values exist and only then use them.
if(isset($_REQUEST['reg_id'], $_REQUEST['App_Name'], $_REQUEST['App_Version']))
{
  $id = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['req_id']) ;
  $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['App_Name']) ;
  $version = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_REQUEST['App_Version']) ;

  $query = "INSERT INTO registration (Reg_ID, APP_Name, App_Version)
    VALUES ('{$id}', '{$name}','{$version}') ;" ;

  $result = mysqli_query($con, $query) ;
  if ($result){
    echo "Success" ;
  } else {
    echo "Failure" ;
  }
} else {
  echo "Not sufficient data for request" ;
}
```

I just corrected the basic flow of conditions and escaped special characters to secure your database. It should work.

Comment: Hmm, why are you showing us your Java code, when getting errors in PHP. Btw I solved your `undefined index` errors in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using $_POST instead of $_REQUEST, if you are POSTing data. And for clarity - in line 7 and below reuse assigned variables ($Reg_ID, $App_Name, $App_Version) instead of $_REQUEST[...].

Comment: What these functions output: print_r($_GET) and print_r($_POST)? Show us your full Android form submission code, maybe you are passing those values as query string not form params.

Comment: Android code looks +/- OK. Show us contents of $_GET and $_POST.