# Change Volley timeout duration

Tags: android, timeout, android-volley

I use the new Volley framework for Android to do a request to my server. But it timeouts before getting the response, although it does respond.

I tried adding this code:

```
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, 5000);
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, timeoutMs);
```

in `HttpClientStack` of the Volley framework to a different integer (50000), but it still times out before 50 seconds.

Is there a way to change the timeout to a long value?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk - this wouldn't be a duplicate as it is about specific details in the Volley framework. The referenced SO question if about the use of the `HttpClient` class.

Answer (score 387, accepted):

See `Request.setRetryPolicy()` and the constructor for `DefaultRetryPolicy`, e.g.

```
JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
        url, null,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
            }
});

myRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
        MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
        DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: @Markus override Request.getPriority() to return something besides 'normal'. ImageRequest does this.  NOTE: you should be asking this in a separate SO question.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for to prevent Volley from discarding my request which takes 15 sec. - Thanx !

Comment: I just added this for POST requests to disable retry on timeout. It's incredible wrong that Google Developers have decided to set a retry policy on POST requests. Solved my issue. Thanks.

Comment: @larham1 where should i write DefaultRetryPolicy constructor? Volley.jar is of compiled classes. we cant edit that Request.class right?

Comment: @Roon13 see the sample request constructor that was just added.

Comment: How can I make such a change to be used by all requests. Is there a way to override add method of requestQueue so that all the requests use the same modified retry policy?

Comment: @KumarDeepak You have to subclass `*Request` class and set the retry policy there. Refer to [Androiderson's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19235122/2821954)

Answer (score 243):

To handle Android Volley Timeout you need to use **`RetryPolicy`**

### RetryPolicy

- Volley provides an easy way to implement your RetryPolicy for your requests.
- Volley sets default Socket & ConnectionTImeout to 5 secs for all requests.

`RetryPolicy` is an interface where you need to implement your logic of how you want to retry a particular request when a timeout happens.

It deals with these three parameters

- Timeout - Specifies Socket Timeout in millis per every retry attempt.
- Number Of Retries - Number of times retry is attempted.
- Back Off Multiplier - A multiplier which is used to determine exponential time set to socket for every retry attempt.

For ex. If RetryPolicy is created with these values

> Timeout - 3000 ms, Num of Retry Attempts - 2, Back Off Multiplier - 2.0

**Retry Attempt 1:**

- time = time + (time * Back Off Multiplier);
- time = 3000 + 6000 = 9000ms
- Socket Timeout = time;
- Request dispatched with Socket Timeout of 9 Secs

**Retry Attempt 2:**

- time = time + (time * Back Off Multiplier);
- time = 9000 + 18000 = 27000ms
- Socket Timeout = time;
- Request dispatched with Socket Timeout of 27 Secs

So at the end of **Retry Attempt 2** if still Socket Timeout happens Volley would throw a `TimeoutError` in your UI Error response handler.

```
//Set a retry policy in case of SocketTimeout & ConnectionTimeout Exceptions. 
//Volley does retry for you if you have specified the policy.
jsonObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: Nice answer @Yakiv Mospan.But on your example, the time of the first attempt is 0 + (3000 * 2) instead of 3000 + (3000 * 2). And the second one 6000 + (3000 * 2).

Comment: 13KZ, I believe you are still wrong regarding time calculations, see my edit and verify against the volley source

Comment: Just a reminder for people using this: **always** use `new DefaultRetryPolicy(` and make sure to **never reuse** a `RetryPolicy` object, as the object is referenced through all the request process, and retry increments are added over the same object timeout value, thus making your future request timeouts grow infinitely

Comment: how is the connection handshake timeout?

Answer (score 23):

Just to contribute with my approach. As already answered, `RetryPolicy` is the way to go. But if you need a policy different the than default for all your requests, you can set it in a base Request class, so you don't need to set the policy for all the instances of your requests.

Something like this:

```
public class BaseRequest<T> extends Request<T> {

    public BaseRequest(int method, String url, Response.ErrorListener listener) {
        super(method, url, listener);
        setRetryPolicy(getMyOwnDefaultRetryPolicy());
    }
}
```

In my case I have a GsonRequest which extends from this BaseRequest, so I don't run the risk of forgetting to set the policy for an specific request and you can still override it if some specific request requires to.

Comment: This should work right? setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                1000, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Answer (score 12):

```
/**
 * @param request
 * @param <T>
 */
public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> request) {

    request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
            MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

    getRequestQueue().add(request);
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
req.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

You can set `MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS` as 100. Whatever you want to set this to is in milliseconds. `DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES` can be 0 default is 1.

Answer (score 5):

```
int MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS=500;

 stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                MY_SOCKET_TIMEOUT_MS,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it is in custom JsonObjectRequest by:

```
@Override
public RetryPolicy getRetryPolicy() {
    // here you can write a custom retry policy and return it
    return super.getRetryPolicy();
}
```

Source: [Android Volley Example](http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-volley-example/)

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution if all above solutions are not working for you

By default, Volley set timeout equally for both `setConnectionTimeout()` and `setReadTimeout()` with the value from `RetryPolicy`. In my case, `Volley` throws timeout exception for large data chunk see:

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.HurlStack.openConnection().
```

My solution is create a class which extends `HttpStack` with my own `setReadTimeout()` policy. Then use it when creates `RequestQueue` as follow:

```
Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext.getApplicationContext(), new MyHurlStack())
```

Answer (score 1):

I ended up adding a method `setCurrentTimeout(int timeout)` to the `RetryPolicy` and it's implementation in `DefaultRetryPolicy`.

Then I added a `setCurrentTimeout(int timeout)` in the Request class and called it .

This seems to do the job.

Sorry for my laziness by the way and hooray for open source.