# How to set connection timeout for volley?

Tags: android, timeout, android-volley

I know volley have a Retry Policy,but what i know , this is for a socket timeout,not for a connection timeout, Apache HttpClient have setConnectionTimeout and setSoTimeout Method,is anyone know if i want to set connection timeout for volley framework.

Comment: did u checked this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/android-volley-timeout?answertab=active#tab-top)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to set the Parameters of any existing HTTPClient (e.g. DefaultHttpClient or AndroidHttpClient) you can use `setParams().`

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();

int timeoutConnection = 3000;
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);

int timeoutSocket = 5000;
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
```

// after this set the parameters

```
httpClient.setParams(httpParameters);
```

Refer this:
[How to set HttpResponse timeout for Android in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java)

Comment: Hope this may help you!

Comment: then did you refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/android-volley-timeout  ??

Comment: I have seen this before i asked.But i think RetryPolicy is just for socket timeout, not for a connection timeout. maybe i am wrong understand the difference between connection timeout and socket timeout???so confused,,,

Comment: the reference is correct,i found this in the source code.

Answer (score 2):

you must open the `HttpClientStack` under package `com.android.volley.toolbox;` and then at the body of function `performRequest` you can change the values of

```
  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParams, your time);
  HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParams, your time);
```

hope it helps.

Comment: Connection timeout is set to 5000 by default, but the actual time out happens after 40 seconds. How do I set the connection timeout.