# Exception handling in android volley networking library

Tags: android, android-volley

How about exception handling in volley, does it provide exception handling mechanism in build or we need to handle it separately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you create a request object in `Volley` you need to specify an error listener, Volley invokes the `onErrorResponse` callback method of that listener passing an instance of the `VolleyError` object when there is an error while performing the request.

The following is the list of exceptions in Volley:

`AuthFailureError` — If you are trying to do Http Basic authentication then this error is most likely to come.

`NetworkError` — Socket disconnection, server down, DNS issues might result in this error.

`NoConnectionError` — Similar to NetworkError, but fires when the device does not have Internet connection, your error handling logic can club `NetworkError` and `NoConnectionError` together and treat them similarly.

`ParseError` — While using `JsonObjectRequest` or `JsonArrayRequest` if the received JSON is malformed then this exception will be generated. If you get this error then it is a problem that should be fixed instead of being handled.

`ServerError` — The server responded with an error, most likely with 4xx or 5xx HTTP status codes.

`TimeoutError` — Socket timeout, either server is too busy to handle the request or there is some network latency issue. By default, `Volley` times out the request after 2.5 seconds, use a RetryPolicy if you are consistently getting this error.

Source: http://arnab.ch/blog/2013/08/asynchronous-http-requests-in-android-using-volley/

Comment: It means we need to handle it separately.?

Comment: Volley itself handled exception. If you want to customize those exception you can catch exception onErrorResponse method.

Comment: If my response make you understand. Accept my answer.

Comment: hey @Sathish, _Volley times out the request after 2.5 seconds_? I thought it was 5 sec.

http://stackoverflow.com/a/22169775/6561141