# Connection time-out error in Android device while calling Rest-APIs

Tags: android, connection-timeout

I am trying to call Rest-APIs in android. But it gives me connection time-out error in real device most of the time. From 5 tries it return me 4 time this error.

While the same thing work perfect in Emulator. I have tried Rest-APIs calling using different techniques(Volley, HttpClient, Retrofit), but same error returned.

I have deployed Rest-APIs in GoDaddy server.

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.GET, url,
            getSuccessListener(listener), getErrorListener(listener)) {
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("Authorization", Authorization);
            return params;
        }
    };
    strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(15 * 1000, 5,
            DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
    queue.add(strReq);
```

Comment: I think depends on your net connection speed. are you sure you are using good network?.. if yes try some other url.

Comment: @Ancee I tried many urls. And I am using network with speed 21 mbps

Comment: hitting on same server?.. and had you try hit this urls on web browser?

Comment: @Ancee Yes I tried this in web browser and also these apis work perfect in IOS devices

Answer (score 0):

**If you are connecting to Rest api using your own code then do the following.**

Increase connection time out using

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
conn.setReadTimeout(15000);  // time is in milliseconds
conn.setConnectTimeout(15000);  // so this will wait for 15 seconds
```

This may solve your problem.

**If you are using valley then check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration)**

Comment: I have tried both the solution. But the same problem again

Comment: I am using above code and it return me "com.android.volley.TimeoutError"