# Calling URL and Retry logic in Android application

Tags: android

I have a Java Spring web application running & can be pulled up through an URL.  The web application runs in a loop to display different contents.  Also I wrote an android app that launches the URL using WebView after Android boot complete so far so good.  But I am looking for some ideas on retry logic or restart android app to open the URL if the URL is down in the middle?. The intention is to avoid user intervention, Can somebody shed some light on it?.  Thanks.

Comment: You could try using [Volley's DefaultRetryPolicy](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17179436/2308683)

Comment: Thanks, so far what I have read is that the retry logic work on only at the begining when it calls the URL?.  I am looking for something when the URL is in the middle of pumping the content (Screen1, Screen2 ....), do you know by any chance will this Volley's Retry support?.  Thanks.