# Different response from Volley request when Internet connecting 4G and 2G

Tags: android, android-volley

In project I am implementing **"Add to favorite"** that when adding have to will record in server DB.

I am getting list of product from json

```
{
    "id": 37,
    "name": "Apple",
    "price": 205,
    "photo": "~/IMG/Full/20166117138.jpg",
    "favorite": false
  },
```

If user added item **"to favorite"** - I am do POST Request using Volley.

```
URL?user_id=1095&product_id=37
```

After this POST Request the parameter **"favorite"** will be changed to ***"true"***

When user add some item to favorite, I am checking connecting timeout I using timer

```
 waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000,300) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }
                        public void onFinish() {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Check connecting to internet ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }.start();
```

After 15 sec if mobile not connected with internet, I show message *"Check connecting to internet "*. If mobile is connected and got response from server timer is stoped and item added to favorite, changing icon.

**Problem:**  All this work fine when user connected with WI-FI or with faster mobile internet, but when  weakly internet connecting  although the requset comes from server it stayed show message *"Check connecting to internet "*.

I am use `RecyclerView`.

```
public class PrudactAdapterC extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PrudactAdapterC.PrudactViewHolder> {
@Override
    public void  onBindViewHolder(final PrudactViewHolder prudactViewHolder, final int i) {
    prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setEnabled(false);
                prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setEnabled(false);
                if (p.getFav()==false){

                    myFadeInAnimation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext, R.anim.fade_in);
                    prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.startAnimation(myFadeInAnimation);

                   waitTimer = new CountDownTimer(15000,300) {
                        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        }
                        public void onFinish() {
                            Toast.makeText(mContext,"Check connecting to internet ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.clearAnimation();
                            myFadeInAnimation.cancel();

                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setEnabled(true);
                            prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setEnabled(true);

                            /*p.setFav(false);
                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_out);*/
                        }
                    }.start();

                    addToFav(p.getId(), prudactViewHolder, p);

                }

                else {

                   //

                }
            }
        });
        }

         void addToFav(final int id, final PrudactViewHolder prudactViewHolder, final PrudactModel p){

        String url = URLADD + "userid="+getClientId()+"&tovarid="+id;

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {

                        if (response.equals("1"))
                        {
                            if(waitTimer != null) {
                                waitTimer.cancel();
                                waitTimer = null;
                            }

                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.clearAnimation();
                            myFadeInAnimation.cancel();

                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_in);
                            p.setFav(true);

                            prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setEnabled(true);
                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setEnabled(true);

                        }
                        else  {

                            if(waitTimer != null) {
                                waitTimer.cancel();
                                waitTimer = null;
                            }

                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.clearAnimation();
                            myFadeInAnimation.cancel();

                         /*   prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_out);
                            p.setFav(false);*/

                            prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setEnabled(true);
                            prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setEnabled(true);
                        }
                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Check connecting to internet",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(waitTimer != null) {
                            waitTimer.cancel();
                            waitTimer = null;
                        }

                        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.clearAnimation();
                        myFadeInAnimation.cancel();

//                        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon_favorite_out);
//                        p.setFav(false);

                        prudactViewHolder.ll_favorite.setEnabled(true);
                        prudactViewHolder.btn_favorite.setEnabled(true);


                    }
                }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                return params;
            }
        };
                 RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mContext);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }

        }
```

If my method to implementing **"Add to favorite"** not right... let me know))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of your `CountDownTimer` implementation i'd suggest you to use `RetryPolicy`.

You could do something like this:

```
stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
    15000, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Much easier to maintain and should fix your problem.

For more info in `RetryPolicy` check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169775/3363481).

To show your `Toast`, you could do the following:

```
@Override
public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    if(error instanceof TimeoutError || error instanceof NoConnectionError) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext,"Check your internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // ...
    }
}
```