# Volley library is throwing network error in 2g network and working in 3g and wifi

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using 'compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19' library.
Api's are working 3g and wifi fine but in 2g network it is not working.

Comment: you should change its default time out

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169775/6244429

Comment: @NaveedAli changed default time out to 60000