# Android volley getting Error response when the network is too slow

Tags: android, android-studio, android-volley

Hi I am getting the Error response for the requests when the network is too slow even though the request is successfully send to the server? Could someone please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration

Comment: use retryPolicy on your stringRequest and control the connection time.

Comment: Thanks Pavneet. But I do not want to retry

Comment: @Ibrahim, Already he retryPolicy is in lace.

Answer (score 0):

set value to response time out like

```
  stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new RetryPolicy() {
        @Override
        public int getCurrentTimeout() {
            // Here goes the new timeout 3 minutes
            return 3*60*1000;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCurrentRetryCount() {
            // The max number of attempts
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public void retry(VolleyError error) throws VolleyError {

        }
    });
```

You should use above time out  before  two lines

```
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Comment: I have already added   jsonObjRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                50000,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

Comment: please increase time . The max number of attempts decrease

Comment: Set the time 50 sec and the retry is 0

Answer (score 0):

**Volley makes more than one call to same API, if the network is slow that gives misleading results. To avoid this scenario add setRetryPolicy flag before adding request to volley queue.**

```html
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(………….); 
jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(0,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT.BACKOFF_MULT)); 
SingletonClass.getInstance.addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq);
```

Answer (score 0):

> Try this code , it lets the api to wait for api response for some
>   particular time period(provided by you)

```
// time provided to wait for api response
     jsonObjReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    10000,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));

            // Adding request to request queue
            AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, cancel_change_api);
        }
```