# Request Volley, the data received sometimes and sometimes not

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I am trying to make request with `Volley` android library, but sometimes I receive data and sometimes It fails, am I doing anything wrong?

Here's the code which I'm using to make the request

```
StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            Config.EDIT_KERANJANG_URL, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, " Response: " + response.toString());

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Config.SUCCESS = jsonObject.getString("success");

                Log.e("error", "nilai sukses=" + Config.SUCCESS);

                if (Config.SUCCESS.equals("1")) {

                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("CODE_RESUME_EDITK", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                    editor.putString("code_resume_editk", "1");
                    editor.apply();
                    finish();

                }
                else {
                    Log.e("error", "tidak bisa ambil data 0");
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("error", "tidak bisa ambil data 1");
                Toast.makeText(KeranjangEditActivity.this, "Gagal menyimpan!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    },

            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Login Error: " + error.getMessage());
                    Toast.makeText(KeranjangEditActivity.this,
                            "Gagal menyimpan!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            })

    {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            // Posting parameters to login url
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id_pesanan", sidPesanan);
            params.put("quantity", sQuantity);
            params.put("harga", sHarga);

            return params;
        }

    };
```

And here's my custom adapter which I'm using to populate the list item.

```
public class KeranjangAdapter extends BaseAdapter  {

public static final int TYPE = 2;
private Context context;
private String idUserH,idProdukH,idKeranjangH,idFileH;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<KeranjangModel> keranjangModels = new ArrayList<KeranjangModel>();
private int grandTotal = 0;
SessionManager sessionManager;
NumberFormat rupiahFormat;

private ColorDrawable[] vibrantLightColorList =
        {
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffeead")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#93cfb3")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#fd7a7a")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#faca5f")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#1ba798")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#6aa9ae")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ffbf27")),
                new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#d93947"))
        };

public ColorDrawable getRandomDrawbleColor() {
    int idx = new Random().nextInt(vibrantLightColorList.length);
    return vibrantLightColorList[idx];
}

public KeranjangAdapter(Context ctx, List<KeranjangModel> keranjangModels) {
    this.context = ctx;
    this.keranjangModels = keranjangModels;
}

public int getGrandTotal(){
    return grandTotal;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return keranjangModels.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
    return keranjangModels.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    sessionManager = new SessionManager(context);
    HashMap<String, String> user = sessionManager.getUserDetails();
    idUserH = user.get( SessionManager.KEY_ID );

    if (inflater == null)
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    if (convertView == null)
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_keranjang_list, null);

    View vv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_keranjang, parent, false);
    final CheckBox checkBoxs = (CheckBox) vv.findViewById(R.id.checkAll);

    parent.setDescendantFocusability(ListView.FOCUS_BLOCK_DESCENDANTS);

    final ImageView thumbNail = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.fotoProdukK);
    final TextView spOrder = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textInfoK);
    final TextView hargaSatuan = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hargaSatuanK);
    final TextView harga = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textInfoHargaK);
    final TextView idKeranjang = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idKeranjangK);
    final TextView idProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idProdukK);
    final TextView idFile = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.idFileK);
    final TextView quantity = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.jumOrderK);
    final ImageButton hapusK = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.hapusK);
    final ImageButton editK = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editK);
    final TextView namaProduk = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.namaProdukK);
    final CheckBox checkBox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkItem);

    final KeranjangModel m = keranjangModels.get(position);

    Picasso.with(context)
            .load(m.getFotoProdukK())
            .placeholder(getRandomDrawbleColor())
            .into(thumbNail);

    int qty = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.getQuantityK()));
    int harg = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.getHargaK()));
    int id = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.getIdKeranjangK()));
    int idp = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.getIdProdukK()));
    int idf = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.getIdFileK()));
    int hs = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(m.getHargaSatuanK()));

    rupiahFormat = NumberFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMANY);
    String rupiah = rupiahFormat.format(harg);

    quantity.setText(String.valueOf(qty));
    spOrder.setText(m.getSpesifikasiOrderK());
    hargaSatuan.setText(String.valueOf(hs));
    harga.setText(rupiah);
    idKeranjang.setText(String.valueOf(id));
    idProduk.setText(String.valueOf(idp));
    idFile.setText(String.valueOf(idf));
    namaProduk.setText(m.getNamaProdukK());

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkBoxs.setChecked(false);
            Toast.makeText(context, "toas", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });



    return convertView;
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide error details?

Comment: no errors are logged out (logcat) @RohitKhatri

Comment: Are you getting any response from the server, status code and response string?

Comment: yes, I have received a response from the server (json), but the view does not appear, and on the logcat there is writing decorView, stop, etc. is there an error on my adapter?, and does the error occur on the list item (xml) for it?   Thanks @Rohit Khatri

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is issue related to time out. You can set RetryPolicy for the request that you're sending. Use this

```
strReq.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(5000, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, 
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

I hope this will solve the issue.

Comment: what is the usefulness of the 5000 value? Thanks @ZeeshanShabir

Comment: Its is retry policy. You can change the value as per your use-case. You can hit and try different values but by default volley use 5 sec so you will have to use more than 5 sec in your case. You can also look upon this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/22169775/5275639 it perfectly explained there.

Comment: I have added the following code, but there is still an error on the decorView