# Volley file not downloaded using GSM

Tags: android, android-volley

I am using Volley to download a file from AWS. The file size is around 6 mb. In Android docs it is mentioned you should not download a large file  using Volley. So what is the limit to the file size on Volley.
I am using different network type and signal strength on emulator to check how my app behaves while downloading the file. I mainly want to check for GSM network type. If i keep Network type as GSM and even if my signal strength is great, i am getting timeout.  If my Network Type is Full or LTE, the file gets downloaded very quickly. For GSM i even increased the retry limit to 5 minutes but still it gives me timeout. I dont want to allow the retry policy to be grater than 10 seconds. Here is my code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  {

    InputStreamVolleyRequest request;
    private TextView textView;
    private Button button;
    //private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    //WifiManager wifiManager;
     long FILE_SIZE ;
    long startTime;
    long endTime;
    private long takenTime;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView = findViewById(R.id.tv);
        button = findViewById(R.id.button);
        String mUrl="my url";
//        wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                textView.setText("");


                MySingleton.getMySingleton(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(request);

//                requestQueue.add(request);
                button.setEnabled(false);

            }
        });

//        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        request = new InputStreamVolleyRequest(Request.Method.GET, mUrl, new Response.Listener<byte[]>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(byte[] response) {
                if(response!=null){
                    FileOutputStream outputStream;


                    String name = "justdownloaded.mp3";

                    try {

                        outputStream = openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

                        outputStream.write(response);

                        outputStream.close();
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Download complete.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        textView.setText("Complete");

                        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();


                        File file1 = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath(),name);
                        Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: "+MD5.calculateMD5(file1));
                        boolean b =MD5.checkMD5(request.responseHeaderETag,file1);
                        Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: "+b);
                        FILE_SIZE = file1.length();
                        int fileSize = (int) (FILE_SIZE / 1024);

                        takenTime = endTime - startTime;
                        double s = (double) takenTime / 1000;
                        double speed = fileSize / s;
                        Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(speed)
                                + "kb/second"+fileSize);

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    button.setEnabled(true);

                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                if(error != null){
                    if(error.getClass().equals(TimeoutError.class)){
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Time Out Error",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

//                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.i("TAG", "onErrorResponse: "+error.networkResponse);
                Log.i("TAG", "onErrorResponse2: "+error.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.i("TAG", "onErrorResponse3: "+error.getMessage());

                Log.i("TAG", "onErrorResponse4: "+error.getNetworkTimeMs());
                Log.i("TAG", "onErrorRespons5: "+error.getCause());
                Log.i("TAG", "onErrorRespons6: "+error.getStackTrace().toString());
                takenTime = endTime - startTime;
                button.setEnabled(true);
                textView.setText("Error");
                double s = (double) takenTime / 1000;
                double speed = FILE_SIZE / s;
                Log.i("TAG", "onResponse: "+new DecimalFormat("##.##").format(speed) + "kb/second");

            }
        });

        request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(8000,
                2,
                2));

    }

}
```

All the log statements in the error listener returns null. I am able to see the TimeOut toast for GSM. Is it possible to do this for GSM using Volley instead of Download Manager?
I can't use Retrofit as client's requirement is Volley
What should i do differently for efficient download of file from server using GSM in minimum time

Comment: Have you tried RetryPolicy? https://stackoverflow.com/q/17094718/7012517

Comment: @Shobhit yes. I have mentioned in the code that I have set the retry policy to 5 minutes

Answer (score 1):

If you want to download file within application with large size you can use https://github.com/amitshekhariitbhu/Fast-Android-Networking.

```
 public void downloadFile(String url) {

        AndroidNetworking.download(url, Utils.getRootDirPath(this), fileName)
                .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
                .setMaxAgeCacheControl(1000, TimeUnit.DAYS)
                .build()
                .setDownloadProgressListener(new DownloadProgressListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(long bytesDownloaded, long totalBytes) {
                        int per = (int) ((bytesDownloaded * 100) / totalBytes);

                    }
                })
                .startDownload(downloadListener);
    }
```

Comment: I have to use Volley, I can't use any other networking library as the project is almost to completion and changing the library can create unnecessary complications according to the client

Comment: You only need to use new library ,where you are loading a Big files,for other all cases it's not need to change it