# Show retry and stop progress bar after 10 sec, if fail to fetch data

Tags: android, internet-connection

I am fetching data from API using Volley and showing in recycler view and showing **progress bar** till data isn't loaded, now the problem is sometime it takes a lot of time to fetch data and it keeps showing progress bar too .
What I want is, if it takes more than 10 sec then **progress bar** should stop and show check internet connection with retry button on another layout.

Here is my code.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_one, container, false);
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("country", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String country = sharedPref.getString("selectedCountry", "au");
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.pbFragOne);
    listRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.headlines_recycler);
    RecyclerView.LayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
    listRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    listRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    listRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    latestNewsResponse();
    return view;
}
public void latestNewsResponse() {
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            String str_response = response.toString();
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            News news = gson.fromJson(str_response, News.class);
            news_list = news.getArticles();
            if (!news.getStatus().contentEquals("ok")) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Check your connection", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            newsListAdapter = new NewsListAdapter(getContext(), news_list);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            listRecyclerView.setAdapter(newsListAdapter);

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getContext());
    requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
}
```

Comment: Are you using [Request.setRetryPolicy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration/17179436#17179436) ?

Comment: I did but it's not working, so I remove it

Answer (score 1):

If you using Observable, just create `Observable.interval` fill interval and timeunit as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HandlerThread class: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/HandlerThread

```java
public void start10SecondsTimeout() {
        final HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("MyHandlerThread");
        handlerThread.start();
        Looper looper = handlerThread.getLooper();
        final Handler handler = new Handler(looper);
        final Date initialTime = new Date();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Date currentTime = new Date();
                long elapsed = currentTime.getTime() - initialTime.getTime();
                if (elapsed > 10000) {
                    // update ui here
                    handler.removeCallbacks(this);
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
```

This code runs once a second, you can choose yourself how often HandlerThread is scheduled.

Comment: can you please tell me where to add your code, I uploaded my code

Comment: Looking to your code, I think you should use Volley retry policy as suggested