# What is the default time for volley to timeout the request?

Tags: android, android-volley

What is the default time for volley to timeout the request in android when we call any API using volley.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration

Answer (score 2):

Volley has set default Connection timeout to 2.5 sec for socket and 5 sec for http calls seconds.

See this https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/DefaultRetryPolicy.java

and https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/HttpClientStack.java

You can use `RetryPolicy` to update it.

See this https://github.com/google/volley/blob/master/src/main/java/com/android/volley/RetryPolicy.java