# Is it possible to set network call timeout more than 60 seconds.

Tags: android, android-volley, retrofit, retrofit2

I have some network calls that takes can take more than a minute to respond, so i want to set requests timeout to 180 seconds.

I tried this code, but it looks like that after 60 seconds it cancels the request and does not read the timeout property.

This is my code.

```
            jsonObjectRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                    (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(185),
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                    DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
```

Comment: yes used retrofit 2.0

Comment: @Android Team, so its not possible with `volley`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change Volley timeout duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17094718/change-volley-timeout-duration)

Comment: @KaranMer : I know how to change request duration, but i want to know the possibility of increasing timeout duration more than 60 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible with retrofit 2. try this code below

```
int timeOut = 3 * 60; // duration in seconds
    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(timeOut, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build();

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl("your netwrok url")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .client(client)
            .build();

YourRetrofitInterface service = retrofit.create(YourRetrofitInterface.class);
```