# How do you set timed ProgressDialog?

Tags: java, android, json

I have this code: 
class AttemptLogin extends AsyncTask {

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MyAkan.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Attempting login...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        int success;
        String idnumber = etIdnumber.getText().toString();
        String password = etPassword.getText().toString();

        try {
            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("idnumber", idnumber));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(LOGIN_URL, "POST",
                    params);

            success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
            if (success == 1) {
                Log.d("Login Successful!", json.toString());

                Intent i = new Intent("com.gpplsmje.mac.akan.AKANMENU");
                String id = json.getString(TAG_IDNUMBER);
                i.putExtra("idnumber", id);
                finish();
                startActivity(i);
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            } else if (success == 0) {
                Log.d("Login Failure!", json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE));
                return json.getString(TAG_MESSAGE);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pDialog.dismiss();
        if (file_url != null) {
            Toast.makeText(MyAkan.this, file_url, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}
```

This app connects to a server and returns encoded JSON data. Whenever I test it on a local server on my machine, it works fine. It connects fine with the server. But when I turn off my server and use the app, the app loads but stops after a minute or so of login attempt. Is there a way to time the progress for maybe 20sec maximum, and then if it consumes the time it must dismiss the progressdialog and return to the main activity?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your jsonParser object use [HTTPURLConnection](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to do http requests ? If so there is a method [setConnectTimeout](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html#setConnectTimeout%28int%29).

If you are using [DefaultHttpClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/impl/client/DefaultHttpClient.html) take a look a this question [How to set HttpResponse timeout for Android in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java)

Remember that above android 2.2 it's better to use HTTPURLConnection take a look at http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2011/09/androids-http-clients.html for more details.

Comment: I'm not using HTTPURLConnection. I just used DefaultHttpClient and HttpPost for the connection.

Comment: Take a look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java

Comment: I've looked at the link and added it in my jsonParser code. it won't work. In the link it used HttpGet, will it work with HttpPost? that's what im using right now. Im still working on HTTPURLConnection. Thankz.