# Code for checking Internet connection is not working properly

Tags: android

I am developing an app in which I need to check if an internet connection is available or not. The code I have written seems to handle all cases but it is not working in my emulator. My code:

```
public boolean hasConnection() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }

        NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The problem is that it is never returning `false` whether the internet connection is available or not, both in a device and in my emulator. But it is working well if the device is connected with wifi connection. What problem with that snippet?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17717749/check-for-active-internet-connection-android

Comment: What you mean by it never return false and working well if device connected with wifi? 
If it never return false then how can it work well with wifi ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this method.

```
private boolean IsNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mActiveNetworkInfo = mConnectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return mActiveNetworkInfo != null && mActiveNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

You will also need:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: whats the problem with this answer.? can down votter give me ans of that.?