# Xamarin - Android Lost WiFi Connection

Tags: android, xamarin, wifi

Hello the android app that I am making, after a few hours on stand-by lost the WiFi connection. I tried with a timer and check connection but the application freezes after a few hours and continue to lost connection.

Comment: try to clean and rebuild the project

Comment: I've already tried but the timer will stop working after a few hours the smartphone lost the connection

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18285172/code-for-checking-internet-connection-is-not-working-properly)

Comment: Thank you. The control works but after a few hours in standby the smartphone loses the connection and the application freezes and when the phone resumes, it resumes the timer and it takes a few seconds to connect at the wifi(I have to make it immediately in the background)

Comment: put the code here you have done

Answer (score 1):

I think when the phone is  in stand by the activity is going to be paused eventually stoped, for this reason the event paused eventually also stopped is going to be called, after pressing the home button the function Resume may be also start is going to be called.

Please have a look to this article 
https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html

from my perspective the time should be stoped when the app in background or phone in stand by

For connectivity I will advice you to use the connectivity Module from Nuget, this plugin is really stable.