# Killing or stoping a background thread if the http call fails or not reachable in android

Tags: android, http, connection, request, blocking

I am doing below (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)) but if server is not reachable or unavailable it doesn't give the control back to the thread after 2-3 seconds. Done making request is printed after 10-15 seconds. Any idea why.

```
public JSONArray makeHttpRequest(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
                    
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
        int timeoutConnection = 2000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 2000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);

        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);           
        
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    Log.d("error_trace", "Done making request");
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        errorFlag = true;
    }
```

Comment: it could be caused by latency in your data connection. see if it makes a difference if you're connected via wireless versus no-wireless.

Comment: no basically i shutdown wireless and 4G and then see that control comes back after 10+ seconds to thread.