# Connection Time Out

Tags: android, timer, httprequest, httpresponse

Right now I am using HTTPRequest   every thing is working fine.
But i want to handle the  following scenario

**`Device is connected to wifi but wifi is not connected to internet`**

I am using conection time out but honestly speaking it take its own time to time out and that is 40 seconds not less than that. Code for Request (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)) is following :

```
  public String[] doHttpGetWithCode_1(String url, String headerParam) throws Exception {
            
        
         weburl         = new URL(url);
         uri            = new URI(weburl.getProtocol(), weburl.getUserInfo(), weburl.getHost(), weburl.getPort(), weburl.getPath(), weburl.getQuery(), weburl.getRef());
         result         = new String[2];
         httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
         timeoutConnection = 3000;
         HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        timeoutSocket   = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        httpURL=(HttpURLConnection) weburl.openConnection();
        httpURL.setDoOutput(true);
        httpURL.setDoInput(true);
        httpURL.setRequestMethod("GET");
        client          =new  DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);  
        httpget = new HttpGet(url);
        httpget.addHeader("Content-Type",   "application/json");
        httpget.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(("greggs:sausage123").getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
        httpget.addHeader("X-Auth-Signature",   headerParam);
        httpget.setParams(httpParameters);
        
        try{
            response    = client.execute(httpget);
            entity      = response.getEntity();
            is          = entity.getContent();
//          BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in );
            reader      = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, HTTP.UTF_8));
            sb          = new StringBuilder();
            line        = null;
            
                try {
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                    try {
                        is.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException CPE)
        {
            CPE.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        
            result[0] = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()+"";
            result[1] = sb.toString();
            return result;
        }
```

After running the highlighted scenario i got the following response:

```
10-09 10:42:00.845: W/System.err(6052): java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "xxx.xxx.com": No address associated with hostname
    10-09 10:42:00.850: W/System.err(6052):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
    10-09 10:42:00.850: W/System.err(6052):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
    10-09 10:42:00.855: W/System.err(6052):     at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
    10-09 10:42:00.855: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
    10-09 10:42:00.855: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
    10-09 10:42:00.860: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
    10-09 10:42:00.860: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
    10-09 10:42:00.860: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:670)
    10-09 10:42:00.860: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:509)
    10-09 10:42:00.865: W/System.err(6052):     at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
    10-09 10:42:00.870: W/System.err(6052):     at com.putitout.Utils.Network.doHttpGetWithCode_1(Network.java:363)
    10-09 10:42:00.875: W/System.err(6052):     at com.putitout.GREEGS.Rewards.RewardHomeScreen$18.run(RewardHomeScreen.java:1157)
    10-09 10:42:00.880: W/System.err(6052): Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
    10-09 10:42:00.880: W/System.err(6052):     at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
    10-09 10:42:00.885: W/System.err(6052):     at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:55)
    10-09 10:42:00.885: W/System.err(6052):     at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
    10-09 10:42:00.885: W/System.err(6052):     ... 11 more
    10-09 10:42:00.890: W/System.err(6052): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
    10-09 10:42:00.890: W/System.err(6052):     ... 14 more
```

Now what I need to do is to add timer that runs for specific interval need a little help on this
thank you in advance for your attention .