# internet connection error blocking the app

Tags: android

I have an app that needs internet, when the internet is excellent it works perfectly when there is no internet it works also perfectly because I've adde this code to check wether there is internet or not:

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
              = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    }
```

and if it returns false I make a toast to the user saying that there's no internet;

but when the internet is poor the app gets an error or it just blocks and gets a black screen for 30sec and then show the error...
so what can I do to fix this how can I see if internet is poor and avoid this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the [timeouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java) shorter than 30000 milliseconds to give up earlier. But there really isn't a way to make a poorly working connection work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Use this one:

```
public boolean isConnectingToInternet() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager)this
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if (connectivity != null) {

        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if (info != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {

                    return true;
                }

    }

    return false;
}
```

Now check in your Activity.

```
 if(isConnectingToInternet()){

   // do your stuff using internet

 } else{

   // display Toast here

 }
```

Comment: thnaks but can I know why this code is better than mine? what does it do more?

Comment: In your code you haven't specify that if network is available then it returns true otherwise it false. So whenever you check in activity you can get what you want.

Comment: thanks, but I didn't understand what you mean sorry; because my method also gets me false when there's no connection... Would appreciate if u explain what you mean..

Answer (score 0):

To perform network based operation, AsyncTask should be the choice.