# Android how to show toast on Connection TimeOUT

Tags: android, networking, toast, connection-timeout, http-response-codes

I am using below code (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)) to check the connection time out in Android. On top of this how can I show Toast if connection actually times out? Any suggestion?

```
/*Client timeout*/
HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
// Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
// The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used. 
int timeoutConnection = 3000;        //3Seconds
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
// Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
// in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
int timeoutSocket = 5000;            //5Seconds
HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
/*Client timeout ends*/

final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);

**********************
//HOW TO SHOW TOAST MESSAGE WHEN THIS CASE ACTUALLY OCCURS ??
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use try catch block for that.

```
try{
    //your code of making request
}
catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
    Toast.makeText(context, "Connection timed out.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();    
}
```

Make sure to pass proper context from Activity.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Don't i get anything in response ? i mean something like "504" code ?

Comment: I guess that will return response = null. :) @user45678

Comment: Are you sure ? Then i can directly check for null response ?

Comment: @user45678 You can debug and check using response handler, but I think it won't be a proper way to check for null. Specially, when you can handle using try catch for particular ConnectionTimeoutException in a better way.