# error message "error occured while executing doInBackground" when add Connection Timeout and Socket Timeout

Tags: android, http

I get error message "error occured while executing doInBackground" when add Connection Timeout and Socket Timeout on my http request. like this :

```
11-10 22:15:37.044: E/JavaBinder(8027): !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027): Process: com.ad.tanker, PID: 8027
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: println needs a message
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at android.util.Log.println_native(Native Method)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at android.util.Log.e(Log.java:232)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(ViewFillOrder.java:1405)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at com.ad.tanker.ViewFillOrder$ImageUploadTask.doInBackground(ViewFillOrder.java:1)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
11-10 22:15:49.934: E/AndroidRuntime(8027):     ... 4 more
```

and this is my code (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000))

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
        String err=null;
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {               
            try {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                var_date_confirm = sdf.format(new Date());      
                
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos_1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos_2 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                ByteArrayOutputStream bos_3 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap_photo_1.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos_1);
                bitmap_photo_2.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos_2);
                bitmap_photo_3.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos_3);
                byte[] data_1 = bos_1.toByteArray();
                byte[] data_2 = bos_2.toByteArray();
                byte[] data_3 = bos_3.toByteArray();
                
                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                int timeoutConnection = 5000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                int timeoutSocket = 5000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                
                HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);              
                HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(Variabel.URL_CONFIRM_ACTION);               
                ByteArrayBody bab_1 = new ByteArrayBody(data_1,var_photo_1);
                ByteArrayBody bab_2 = new ByteArrayBody(data_2,var_photo_2);
                ByteArrayBody bab_3 = new ByteArrayBody(data_3,var_photo_3);                
                MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);                   
                reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_ORDER_ID, new StringBody(var_order_id.toString().trim()));
                reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1, bab_1);
                reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1_TIME, new StringBody(var_photo_1_time.toString().trim()));
                reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, new StringBody(var_photo_1_location_longitude.toString().trim()));
                reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1_LOCATION_LATITUDE, new StringBody(var_photo_1_location_latitude.toString().trim()));
                postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
                HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
                String sResponse;
                StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();

                while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    s = s.append(sResponse);
                }
                
                return s.toString().trim();
            
            } catch (Exception e) {
                
                err="error"+e.getMessage();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                
                return e.getMessage();
            }               
        }
```

so how to solve it guys ?
sorry for my english

Answer (score 0):

You should look for the first exception in stack

Actually your error here:

```
 err="error"+e.getMessage();
                Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
```

e.getMessage() == null and you get NullPointerException