# my Android AsyncTask still running when cancelled , how to fix?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

Implemnting Asynctask in my Aplication, But my AsyncTask still running when cancelled and not stop. so how to solve it ? this my code

when I running it

```
myTask = new ImageUploadTask();
myTask.execute();
```

this Asyntask (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000))

```
class ImageUploadTask extends AsyncTask <Void, Void, String>{
            String err=null;
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(Void... unsued) {
                 for(int i = 0; i <= 30000; i++) {
                        if(myTask.isCancelled()) break;
                    }
                
                try {
                    
                    ByteArrayOutputStream bos_1 = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                    bitmap_photo_1.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos_1);
                    byte[] data_1 = bos_1.toByteArray();
                    
                    HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                    // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                    int timeoutConnection = 30*1000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                    // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                    // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                    int timeoutSocket = 30*1000;
                    HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                    
                    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);              
                    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(Variabel.URL_CONFIRM_ACTION);               
                    ByteArrayBody bab_1 = new ByteArrayBody(data_1,var_photo_1);                
                    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
                    
                    reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_USER_ID, new StringBody(Variabel.user_id.toString().trim()));
                    reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1, bab_1);
                    reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1_TIME, new StringBody(var_photo_1_time.toString().trim()));
                    reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1_LOCATION_LONGITUDE, new StringBody(var_photo_1_location_longitude.toString().trim()));
                    reqEntity.addPart(Variabel.KEY_PHOTO_1_LOCATION_LATITUDE, new StringBody(var_photo_1_location_latitude.toString().trim()));
                    
                    postRequest.setEntity(reqEntity);
                    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
                    String sResponse;
                    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
    
                    while ((sResponse = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        s = s.append(sResponse);
                    }
                    
                    return s.toString().trim();
                
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    
                    err="error"+e.getMessage();
                    Log.e(e.getClass().getName(), e.getMessage());
                    
                    return e.getMessage();
                }       
                
            }
```

Canceling code

```
myTask.cancel(true);
```

so how to stop full ?
sorry for my english

Comment: yes but i have set `if(thread.isCancelled()) break;` , this stilll running

Comment: Yes because after it breaks the `for` loop, it goes into the try-catch block, so anyways ends up executing it.

Comment: please how the correct code from my code sir ? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can't just kill asynctask immediately. In order it to stop you should first cancel it:

```
task.cancel(true);
```

and than in asynctask's doInBackground() method check if it's already cancelled:

```
isCancelled()
```

and if it is, stop executing it manually.

Just check isCancelled() once in a while:

```
 protected Object doInBackground(Object... x) {
    while (/* condition */) {
      // work...
      if (isCancelled()) break;
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Comment: but i ready put above code in my code sir...:(