# Async Task and Toast - Android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, toast

I start to do sync for my app with Android Studio. My code is (timeout code based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000)):

```
private class Check_Loguin_Request extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

        //Declaration of variables
        String User = strings[0];
        String Pass = strings[1];
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient;
        HttpPost Request = new HttpPost(url_Loguin);
        HttpResponse Response;
        HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();


        // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
        // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
        int timeoutConnection = 3000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
        // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
        // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
        int timeoutSocket = 5000;
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
        httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);


        List<NameValuePair> BodyRequest_Elements = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        BodyRequest_Elements.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_name", User));
        BodyRequest_Elements.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_passwd", Pass));

        try {
            HttpEntity entity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(BodyRequest_Elements);
            Request.setHeader(entity.getContentType());
            Request.setEntity(entity);

            Response = httpClient.execute(Request);

            HttpEntity entity2 = Response.getEntity();
            InputStream is = entity2.getContent();

            return Response.toString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex){
            Log.getStackTraceString(ex);
            return null;
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Task Finalized: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

This class is a external class(Sync_Class) of my main activity(Loguin_Activity), when i call this in toast ide give me error. Then how can I send Context from my activity? Thanks in advance and sorry for my english!

PD1: If you need more code or info advice me! :D

Comment: Whether the class Check_Loguin_Request is in  Loguin_Activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the your Task class, create a constructor and give it your context like this:

```
private class Check_Loguin_Request
{
  Context cx;
  public Check_Loguin_Request(Context cx)
  {
    this.cx=cx;
  }
}
```

Then in the OnPostExecute use this cx

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result)
{
   Toast.makeText(cx, "Task Finalized: " + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

The use this class like this:

```
Check_Loguin_Request login=new Check_Loguin_Request(getBaseContext());
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass a Context object into the AsyncTask's constructor.

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<?, ? ,?> {
    private Context mContext;

    public MyTask(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    } 
}
```

and then, when you are constructing your AsyncTask:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(this);
task.execute(...);
```

You can display Toast using this mContext reference.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use Context context;
context=this;

Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "Your Text", +3);
toast.show();
```