# How can I show a Toast from AsyncTask onPostExecute?

Tags: java, android, toast

When my `AsyncTask` finishes, I display info in a `TextView`.

```
    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void x)
    {
      MainActivity.lblLastLetterProcessed.setText("A-Z loaded");
    }
```

Like so:

```
  public static void setLastLetterProcessed(char c){
    lblLastLetterProcessed.setText("" + c);
  }
```

I'd rather give the info via `Toast` but `Toast` requires `Context`.

```
protected void onPostUpdate(Integer... progress) 
{
  Toast toast= Toast.makeText(???????????, "Loaded A-Z", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
  toast.show();
}
```

So I wrote `popupMessage`:

```
  void popupMessage(String text)
  {
    SpannableStringBuilder altText = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    altText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFCC5500), 0, altText.length(), 0);
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, altText, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
  }
```

But I can't call it from `onPostUpdate` since `popupMessage` is NOT `static`.

If I make it `static`, I can't use `getApplicationContext`. And if I add `Context` as a parameter, I can't pass `Context` from `onPostUpdate`.

Googling has provided no SO Answers I can implement.

What can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28659165/toast-in-asynctask-in-non-activity-class

Comment: ^ that, and check my answer below

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{
    private Context mContext;

    public MyTask(Context context){
        mContext = context;
    }

    ...
    ... 

    protected void onPostUpdate(Integer... progress){
        Toast toast= Toast.makeText(mContext, "Loaded A-Z", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

and instantiate it like so:

```
MyTask task = new MyTask(MyActivity.this).execute();
```

This is how I do AsyncTask's that require arguments, I also define callbacks this way in the constructor of the Tasks to interact with the activities that call them.

Comment: I would suggest passing the Activity Context for use with a `Toast`. [Read this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7298955/1380752) and [Context, what context](https://possiblemobile.com/2013/06/context/)

Comment: @LucasCrawford--THANKS. I didn't get it right away, but IT WORKS. I'll post the working code.

Comment: Right on, sorry for any ambiguity

Comment: There was NO ambiguity, except that hardwired into my brain.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lucas Crawford, this works:

```
public class ListMaker extends ArrayList<String> 
{
  Context mContext; //////////////////////////////
  ...    

  public ListMaker(AssetManager assets, Context c){
    //                                  ^^^^^^^^^^
    ...    
    mContext = c;  /////////////////////////////////

    LoadWords loadWords = new LoadWords();
    ...
    loadWords.execute((Object []) null);
  }

  private class LoadWords extends AsyncTask<Object, Integer, Void>
  {
    @Override protected Void doInBackground(Object... params) 
    {
       ...
       publishProgress(...);
    }

    @Override protected void onPostExecute(Void x)
    {
      Toast toast= Toast.makeText(mContext, "Loaded A-Z", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
       //                         ^^^^^^^^
      toast.show();

    }
    ...
  }
}
```

And even better I have an improved, more useful `popupMessage` that I can call from `onPostExecute` like so:

```
     MainActivity.popupMessage("Loaded A-Z", mContext);
```

And here it is:

```
  public static void popupMessage(String text, Context context)
  //     ******                                **********
  {
    SpannableStringBuilder altText = new SpannableStringBuilder(text);
    altText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(0xFFCC5500), 0, altText.length(), 0);
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, altText, duration);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
  }
```

Comment: It kind of irritates me when I see how easy something is, why didn't I think of that, but I guess that's how we learn....

Answer (score 0):

I expect you have the async method in a seperate Class

```
package nl.yentel.finekinney;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Demo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
     Activity demoActivity; //this is a public variable

public void ActivityName(Activity activity) {
    //calling this void will set the variable demoActivity to the input activity
    demoActivity = activity;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(demoActivity, "the text in the toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Then I have to call this Class

```
public void openMail(final View view) {
    //first create a pointer to the Demo Class
    Demo JsonConnect = new Demo();
    //then attach the context activity to the ActivityName

    //in the Class 'demoActivity' will point to the calling activity;
    JsonConnect.ActivityName(this);
    JsonConnect.execute();
}
```

Now the toast will point to the proper calling activity

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(demoActivity, "the text in the toast", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```