# Cancel asynctask forcefully doesn't work

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an app that is included a refresh button in actionbar. When I click on it for second time, my app goes to debug view and it says my asyncClass object isn't finished yet !!!

Please let me know how can I fix my problem.

**MyActivity:**

```
public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   private getAllDataFromServer asyncClass;    

   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    asyncClass = new getAllDataFromServer();
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(item.getItemId() == R.id.action_update)
       if(asyncClass.getStatus() == Status.FINISHED || asyncClass.getStatus() == Status.RUNNING)
       {
          asyncClass.cancel(true);
       }
       if(asyncClass.getStatus() == Status.PENDING)
       {
          asyncClass.execute();
       }
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

**getAllDataFromServer:**

```
private class getAllDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SendCommentsHistoryActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Be patient ...");
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if(isCancelled()) return null;
        jObject = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(TAG_URL, param);
        Log.i("JSONNNNNNNNN", jObject.toString());
        try {
            // get json array

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
            {
                // get jsonObjects and fill database
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        fillListView();
        pDialog.dismiss();
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCancelled() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCancelled();
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:** 
**JSONParser class:**

```
public class JSONParser {
static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

public JSONParser() {
}

/**
 * Send POST Data to Server & Retrieve JSON From URL
 */
public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url, List<NameValuePair> params) {
// Making HTTP request
try {
    // defaultHttpClient
    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params,"UTF-8"));
    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    is = httpEntity.getContent();
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
try {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            is, "UTF8"), 8);
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    String line = null;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }
    is.close();
    json = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
}
try {
    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
}
// return JSON Object
return jObj;
}

}
```

**Error screen shot:**
[image]

Any suggestion will be appreciated ...

Comment: show code of refresh button

Comment: the problem is cancel on AsyncTask does not cancel doInBackground process. you must add condition in doInBackground process to check if the process is canceled or not

Comment: I update my code. please check again dears ...

Comment: and FYI, you cannot force end the HttpURLConnection. try to set timeout

Comment: @RandykaYudhistira, I added JSONParser class to my question. please let me know how can I set timeout for HttpURLConnection.

Comment: @FarshadKazemi [This SO post explain it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Once try as follows

```
if(!asyncClass.isCancelled()) {
      asyncClass.cancel(true);
}
```

and in forloop  of doInBackground() write

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    .......................
        // get json array

        for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) 
        {
            // get jsonObjects and fill database

          // Escape early if cancel() is called

           if (isCancelled()) break;
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Hope this will helps you.

Comment: I did it, but it doesn't fix my problem.

Comment: @FarshadKazemi i edited my answer once check have you tried like this only?

Comment: I used your code and change onOptionItemSelected section to     if(!asyncClass.isCancelled()) asyncClass.cancel(true); ayncClass.execute();  But I get the error again

Comment: @FarshadKazemi can you update your code which error you are getting?

Comment: When the asynctask is cancelled as Nag showed, then the `onCancelled()` callback is called instead of `onPostExecute()`. Make sure you are cancelling the dialog and running any other cleanup code in both callbacks