# How to check remaining internet data (cellular data) in android?

Tags: android, internet-connection

We often use below code to check internet...

```
/**
 * Checks if the device has Internet connection.
 * @return <code>true</code> if the phone is connected to the Internet.
 */
public static boolean hasConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) MbridgeApp.getContext().getSystemService(
            Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    NetworkInfo wifiNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    if (wifiNetwork != null && wifiNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo mobileNetwork = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
    if (mobileNetwork != null && mobileNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }

    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or something like this...

```
/**
 * Method is using Connectivity Services to get Connectivity manager. that will find network informations
 * If we found connected state of any network that means we are connected to a network
 * @return true if we are connected otherwise false
 */
public Boolean isConnected() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    if(connectivityManager != null) {
        NetworkInfo[] info = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        if(info != null) {
            for (NetworkInfo i : info) {
                if (i.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Ok, Now the problem is, these both methods will return true even we don't have sufficient mobile/cellular data (Internet Balance) or zero balance. That is not a good condition to perform any task related to the internet like calling an API etc. So question is that how to precise these methods? Can I check data balance programmatically?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java/1565243#1565243

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5803489/1092844

Comment: Your links was helpful, Thanks

Comment: If I may add, those links doesn't help and is not related to the question being asked.

Comment: @mr5 Then why do you not try to answer this question?

Comment: @Khan I would if I knew that's why I made a comment only ;)