# Data being updated/uploaded on the server but no response in Android

Tags: android, json, httpconnection

I am trying to send data on server using JsonParse class.
Now when I try to make a request to the server it always give SocketTimeOut Exception, but on the server side data is being uploaded always.
This means data is uploaded successfully but I did not get response on client side.
I have check my link from browser and getting complete response.

I my Login scenario user get login on server but I did not get user data in response.

**NOTE:**

Actually this problem is happening when wifi or data connection is connected but speed is slow/too slow.

I have search on this issue but did not find satisfactory solution.

**This is class JsonParse** (partly based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1565243/208273) by [kuester2000](https://stackoverflow.com/users/67350/kuester2000))

```
public class JSONParser {

    InputStream is = null;
    JSONObject jObj = null;
    String json = "";
    int timeoutConnection = 3000;

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject mainJson = new JSONObject();
    BufferedReader reader;
    Context context;

    // constructor
    public JSONParser(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    // function get json from url
    // by making HTTP POST or GET mehtod
    public String makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
                                  List<NameValuePair> params) {


        //mobiledataenable(true);

        is = null;
        jObj = null;
        json = "";
        timeoutConnection = 3000;

        jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        mainJson = new JSONObject();

        // Making HTTP request
        try {
            // check for request method
            //if(method == "POST")
            if (method.equals("POST")) {
                // request method is POST
                // defaultHttpClient
                Log.e("JSONParser", "POST METHOD ");

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
                int timeoutConnection = 10000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                int timeoutSocket = 15000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                //Log.e("1111.........",",,,,,,,,"+EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity) );
                is = httpEntity.getContent();
                Log.e("JSONParser is", is.toString());
                return bufferMethod();
            } else if (method == "GET") {

                HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                // Set the timeout in milliseconds until a connection is established.
                // The default value is zero, that means the timeout is not used.
                int timeoutConnection = 10000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
                // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                int timeoutSocket = 15000;
                HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutSocket);
                // request method is GET
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(httpParameters);
                String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");

                if (params.size() != 0)
                    url += "?" + paramString;

                Log.e("JSONParser", "GET METHOD..... " + url);

                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                // Log.e("2222*************.........", ",,,,,,,," + httpResponse.getEntity().getContent().toString());

                HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                is = httpEntity.getContent();

                Log.e("JSONParser is", is.toString());
                return bufferMethod();
            }
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Server timeout", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Log.e("SOCK TIMEOUT", e.toString());
            jObj = null;
            json = new String();
            json = "5";
            return json;
        } catch (ConnectTimeoutException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            jObj = null;
            json = new String();
            return json;
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("UnsupportedEncodingException", e.toString());
            jObj = null;
            json = new String();
            return json;

        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("ClientProtocolException", e.toString());
            jObj = null;
            json = new String();
            return json;

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("IOException", e.toString());
            jObj = null;
            json = new String();
            return json;
        }
        return bufferMethod();
    }

    public String bufferMethod() {

        try {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            reader.close();
            json = new String();
            json = sb.toString();
            Log.e("json to string----", "...." + json);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
            jObj = null;
            json = new String();
            if (e.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("java.net.SocketTimeoutException")) {
                json = "5";
                Log.e("222222----", "...." + json);
            } else {
                json = "6";
                Log.e("333333----", "...." + json);
            }
            return json;
        }

        return json;
    }


}
```

**and this is the request from MainAcivity**

```
public class Logout extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    int response = 0;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String transport_route = "";
    String _number_of_vehicle = "";
    private Exception mException;
    Logout asyncObject;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> TemporaryUploadBackUp = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
    String returnCode = new String();
    String json_string = new String();
    HttpResponse responsee;

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

        asyncObject = this;
     
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(RouteTickiting.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait....");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
       
        returnCode = new String();
    }

    /**
     * getting All BusInfo from url
     */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        // Building Parameters


        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser(RouteTickiting.this);
        jParser = null;
        jParser = new JSONParser(RouteTickiting.this);
        JSONObject jsonReturn = new JSONObject();
        jsonReturn = null;
        returnCode = new String();
        json_string = new String();

        json_string = jParser.makeHttpRequest("some link"?"
                + "user_email=" + user_email +
                "&user_password=" + user_password +
                , "POST", nameValuePairs);

 

        Log.e("loging json data------", "....." + json_string);

        if (json_string.length() == 1) {
            if (json_string.equalsIgnoreCase("5")) {
                returnCode = "5";
                finish();
                session.logoutUser();
            } else if (json_string.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
                returnCode = "6";
            }
        } else {

            try {
                jsonReturn = new JSONObject(json_string);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }

            if (jsonReturn != null) {
                try {

                    Log.e("----logout user......", "..." + jsonReturn);
                    JSONArray error_code = jsonReturn.getJSONArray("result");
                    JSONObject jsonObject = error_code.getJSONObject(0);

                    if (jsonObject.getString("bool").equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
                        //success
                        
                        returnCode = "1";
                        finish();
                        session.logoutUser();
                    } else if (jsonObject.getString("bool").equalsIgnoreCase("0")) {
                        //Already login
                        returnCode = "0";
                        finish();
                        session.logoutUser();
                    } else if (jsonObject.getString("bool").equalsIgnoreCase("2")) {
                        //Unable to login
                        returnCode = "2";
                    } else if (jsonObject.getString("bool").equalsIgnoreCase("3")) {
                        //USer does not exist
                        returnCode = "3";
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        super.onPostExecute(file_url);
 

      
            if (pDialog != null)
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();
       

        if (returnCode.equalsIgnoreCase("6")) {
            customToast("try again");
         
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: can you increase your timeout variable to `60,000` and check

Comment: Yes I increased time out variable but still getting SocketTimeOut. Actually this problem is happening when wifi or data connection is connected but speed is slow/too slow.

Comment: Use Retrofit 2.0 an amazing library for client server REST interaction. You will save a lot of time handling responses and parsing them.

Comment: Yes then in such case you will have to increase `timeout` time, or use some library for network calls for e.g Volley, AndroidAsyncHttp..

Comment: @SatyenUdeshi thankyou for this quick response. So this means Making HTTP request is not a better solution in slow connections. I also tried loopj and same thing was happening in that too. And after rnd on Retrofit it is back-end responsive but not UI responsive. Is this right so?

Comment: personally i have not worked with Retrofit so cannot answer that :D

Comment: @vipin agrahari  after rnd on Retrofit it is back-end responsive but not UI responsive. Is this right so?

Comment: What is the error you are getting when debugging the app?

Comment: @codedByMi SOCK TIMEOUT: java.net.SocketTimeoutException