# Cordova jQuery AJAX call timing out after 30 seconds regardless of timeout setting

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I'm trying to execute the following function on Android to sync with an IoT device I'm making:

```
function NewDeviceFetchDeviceID(){
    strURL = "https://192.168.x.x/.....";

    return $.ajax({
        url: strURL,
        type: 'GET',
        timeout: 90000
    });
}
```

The device takes some time to churn a response to the request (about 45-50 seconds) so I need the timeout to be slightly longer than 30s. The timeout seems to work on iOS - if I set it to 5 seconds it will do so, if I set it for 90 it will wait the whole time. For Android, it seems that this argument is ignored.

I tried adding the following into `config.xml` under `<platform name="android">` with no luck:

```
<preference name="LoadUrlTimeoutValue" value="90000"/>
```

and I tried with a lowercase "L", still no luck:

```
<preference name="loadUrlTimeoutValue" value="90000"/>
```

**How can I properly increase the timeout argument for AJAX requests in a Cordova Android app?**

---

**Update:**
I've changed the function, and I indeed get "Timed out!!!" as the response after exactly 30 seconds:

```
function TryXHR(){
    try{
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                alert("ready state = 4");
            }
        };

        strURL = "https://192.168.x.x/......";
        xhr.open("POST", strURL, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
        xhr.timeout = 120000; // Set timeout to 120 seconds (120000 milliseconds)
        xhr.onload  = function () { alert(xhr.response); }
        xhr.ontimeout = function () { alert("Timed out!!!"); }
        xhr.onerror = function () { alert("Non-timeout error"); }
        xhr.send();
    }catch(err){
        alert("exception caught: "+err.message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it is answered here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/693997/how-to-set-httpresponse-timeout-for-android-in-java

Comment: Unfortunately that's in Java, and I'm writing my app with JavaScript in Cordova

Comment: Did you cross checked server too? There is something called as server timeout too. [Check this](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php) Check in network tab if the request going have an timeout param. Hope that helps :)

Comment: There is no timeout limit on the server side. I can see that server is still decrypting the incoming information from the mobile app, and the (Android) mobile app gives up.

Comment: instead to `return $.ajax({.....` do yuo have tried to use $.ajax `complete()` method to fire your callback? try to set an error function too, to be sure that timeout is the real problem  with the $ajax `error()` method `error: function(x, t, m) {if(t==="timeout") {        alert("got timeout"); } else { alert(t); } }`

Comment: @Sim1-81 see update in original post

Comment: Is your server behind a load balancer?

Comment: @karthick no, the device is just low-resource, hence why the response takes so long to come back

Comment: @Lil' Bits for curiosity, strURL = "https://192.168.x.x/......"; seems to be a local environment, are you sure that you can perform request under HTTPS ? it should be a protocol issue. i got this issue just yesterday with some cUrl request, because the SSL certificate does not been activated on my API server

Comment: @Lil' Bits Another thing, if you can, look out at the code which receive the request, maybe for some reason it would be looped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So after about a month of struggling with this, I ended up using the **Cordova Advanced HTTP** plugin: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-advanced-http

Using the `setRequestTimeout` method, I was able to increase the HTTP request timeout to 120 seconds:

```
cordova.plugin.http.setRequestTimeout(120.0);
```

After rewriting my requests to utilize this plugin, my issues were solved for Android 9/10, and everything still worked as expected for iOS 12/13.